# angular 2.0 equivalent to $scope.$apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am trying to get started with angular 2.0, now I was wondering how I can initiate an update to the view after some external event changed data.

In details I have a google map and a handler for a click-event on the map. After the user clicks on the map I store latitude and longitude of the click in to variables on the controller

```
this.lat = event.latLng.lat();
this.lon = event.latLng.lon();
```

In the view I want to display these values

```
<div> this is my spot: {{lat}} and {{lon}} </div>
```

In angular 1 I would simply wrap the assignment in the controller in a call to $scope.$apply().

What is the preferred way to go about updating views in angluar 2.0 ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mostly, you don't need to do anything to update the view. [zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js) will do everything for you.

But if for some reason you want to fire change detection manually (for example if your code is running outside of an angular zone) you can use [`LifeCycle::tick()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.44/modules/angular2/src/core/life_cycle/life_cycle.ts#L50) method to do it. See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rdezLXMX3ZUraRICOLzM?p=preview)

```
import {Component, LifeCycle, NgZone} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      Hello world!!! Time: {{ time }}.
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  time: number = 0;

  constructor(lc: LifeCycle, zone: NgZone) {
    zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.time = Date.now();

        lc.tick(); // comment this line and "time" will stop updating
      }, 1000);
    })
  }
  doCheck() {
    console.log('check', Date.now());
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! As it seems I was outside of the angular-zone (inside a click-callback of a google-map). Calling the lc.tick() did the trick :-)

Comment: Hmm, maybe [`NgZone:run`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.44/modules/angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone.ts#L212) is more appropriate for your use case. It executes callback inside angular zone, after execution it runs LifeCycle.tick().

Comment: I agrre with @alexpods. There's another question that solves it that way, with `NgZone:run` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352397/how-to-update-view-after-change-in-angular2-after-google-event-listener-fired)

Comment: Another method is using `ChangeDetectorRef` like this: `this.chRef.detectChanges()`.

Comment: LifeCycle doesnt exist anymore :/

Answer (score 53):

Try to import **ChangeDetectorRef** from angular core as follow

```
import {Component, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
```

in constructor

```
constructor(private chRef: ChangeDetectorRef){
  chRef.detectChanges(); //Whenever you need to force update view
}
```

Comment: in new angular versions it is `import {Component, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';`

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout(function(){
//whatever u want here
},0)
```

ref : http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/04/06/angular2-first-impressions/

Comment: This works. Useful fact is that you don't even need the ,0 at the end. You can completely skip that parameter.