# Expression ___ has changed after it was checked

Tags: typescript, angular

Why is the component in this simple [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/VhEGJXE439dohJXNRbPc?p=preview)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div>I'm {{message}} </div>`,
})
export class App {
  message:string = 'loading :(';

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.updateMessage();
  }

  updateMessage(){
    this.message = 'all done loading :)'
  }
}
```

throwing:

> EXCEPTION: Expression 'I'm {{message}}  in App@0:5' has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'I'm loading :( '. Current value: 'I'm all done loading :) ' in [I'm {{message}}  in App@0:5]

when all I'm doing is updating a simple binding when my view is initiated?

Comment: The article [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) explains the behavior in great details.

Comment: Consider modifying your `ChangeDetectionStrategy` when using `detectChanges()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787038/how-to-manage-angular2-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-exception-w/54954374#54954374

Comment: Just think about there is an input control and you are populating data to it in a method and in the same method you are assigning some value to it. The compiler will get confused for sure with the new/ previous value. So binding and populating should happen in different methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manage Angular2 "expression has changed after it was checked" exception when a component property depends on current datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787038/how-to-manage-angular2-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-exception-w)

Comment: As also asked by @Jo-VdB, can't you use ngOnInit() to update bindings ?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

First, note that this exception will only be thrown when you're running your app in dev mode (which is the case by default as of beta-0): If you call [`enableProdMode()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/enableProdMode-function.html) when bootstrapping the app, it won't get thrown ([see updated plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/xO4pCTzxKTKYgFnrr9xl?p=preview)).

Second, **don't do that** because this exception is being thrown for good reason: In short, when in dev mode, every round of change detection is followed immediately by a second round that verifies no bindings have changed since the end of the first, as this would indicate that changes are being caused by change detection itself.

In your plunk, the binding `{{message}}` is changed by your call to `setMessage()`, which happens in the `ngAfterViewInit` hook, which occurs as a part of the initial change detection turn. That in itself isn't problematic though - the problem is that `setMessage()` changes the binding but does not trigger a new round of change detection, meaning that this change won't be detected until some future round of change detection is triggered somewhere else.

The takeaway: **Anything that changes a binding needs to trigger a round of change detection** when it does.

**Update in response to all the requests for an example of how to do that**: @Tycho's solution works, as do the three methods in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35106069/215945) @MarkRajcok pointed out. But frankly, they all feel ugly and wrong to me, like the sort of hacks we got used to leaning on in ng1.

To be sure, there are *occasional* circumstances where these hacks are appropriate, but if you're using them on anything more than a *very* occasional basis, it's a sign that you're fighting the framework rather than fully embracing its reactive nature.

IMHO, a more idiomatic, "Angular2 way" of approaching this is something along the lines of: ([plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qF7DpbMpqjRkTDDI1Ywv?p=preview))

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div>I'm {{message | async}} </div>`
})
export class App {
  message:Subject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('loading :(');

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.message.next('all done loading :)')
  }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't setMessage() trigger a new round of change detection? I thought Angular 2 automatically triggered change detection when you change the value of something in the UI.

Comment: @drewmoore "Anything that changes a binding needs to trigger a round of change detection when it does". How? Is it a good practice? Shouldn't everything be completed in a single run?

Comment: @MarcJ.Schmidt, to manually run change detection, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33821833/215945).  I had a component configured with with `onPush` change detection, so I also had to call `markForCheck()` on an injected ChangeDetectorRef before calling `tick()` on the injected ApplicationRef for the view to update.

Comment: @MarkRajcok: the `tick` approach you linked runs change detection for the whole application. That's fine for the current question, but may yield performance problems in larger applications. In those cases you can instead use `ChangeDetectorRef`'s `detectChanges()`; see my answer for a fixed version of the question's plunker.

Comment: @Tycho, indeed.  Since I wrote that comment, I've answered another question where I describe the [3 ways to run change detection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35106069/215945), which includes `detectChanges()`.

Comment: just to note that, in current question body, the invoked method is named `updateMessage`, not `setMessage`

Comment: Hi. Stupid question: this is happening to me if I try to set the focus from within the AfterView event: window.setTimeout( () => this._servico.input.focus(), 0 );. Changing the interval to 100ms seems to make the error go away. why? thanks,

Comment: In my project i had to inject the ChangeDetectorRef in my component and call its detectChanges methods

Comment: your plunker shows the expression has been changed after check- error

Comment: @Daynil, I had the same feeling, until I read the blog given in comment under the question:
https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

It explains why this needs to be manually done. In this case, angular's change detection has a lifecycle. In case something is changing a value in between these lifecycles, then a forceful change detection needs to be run (or a settimeout - which executes in next event loop, triggering the change detection again).

Comment: calling enableProdMode() fixed my issue

Comment: This is the kind of team leader I want to work under.  Kudos.

Comment: Working link to the blog @Mahesh posted
https://indepth.dev/posts/1001/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error

Comment: We use behavioursubjects for our loaders everywhere and it used to work perfectly fine. Than I removed hybrid and now I have these random not always occurring errors of this message... eventhough everything is properly done in the ngOnInit #magic

Comment: As pointed out by @Pascal using an observable still causes the error.  One solution however is force the observable to use asyncScheduler.  This is effectively the same as the setTimeout solution but more inline with the observable patter

Answer (score 440):

As stated by drewmoore, the proper solution in this case is to manually trigger change detection for the current component. This is done using the `detectChanges()` method of the `ChangeDetectorRef` object (imported from `angular2/core`), or its `markForCheck()` method, which also makes any parent components update. Relevant [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/mSnsKXUCoxPqrmr3wpHz?p=preview):

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef, AfterViewInit } from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div>I'm {{message}} </div>`,
})
export class App implements AfterViewInit {
  message: string = 'loading :(';

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.message = 'all done loading :)'
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

Here are also Plunkers demonstrating the [ngOnInit](http://plnkr.co/edit/TYzIfK?p=preview), [setTimeout](http://plnkr.co/edit/ieoZH1bPG4LtPkqW9X9r), and [enableProdMode](http://plnkr.co/edit/u20wmTzq6jtwVS2dxZiw?p=preview) approaches just in case.

Comment: In my case I was opening a modal. After open the modal it was showing the message "Expression ___ has changed after it was checked", so my solution was added this.cdr.detectChanges(); after open my modal. Thanks!

Comment: Where is your declaration for the cdr property? I would expect to see a line like `cdr : any` or something like that under the `message` declaration. Just worried I've missed something?

Comment: @CodeCabbie it's in the constructor arguments.

Comment: This resolution fix my problem! Thanks a lot! Very clear and simple way.

Comment: This helped me - with a few modifications.  I had to style li elements that were generated via ngFor loop.  I needed to change the color of spans within the list items based on innerText upon clicking 'sort' which updated a bool being used as a parameter of a sort pipe (the sorted result was a copy of the data, so styles weren't getting updated with ngStyle alone).
- Instead of using 'AfterViewInit', I used **'AfterViewChecked'**
- I also made sure to *import* and *implement* AfterViewChecked.  *note: setting the pipe to 'pure: false' was not working, I had to add this extra step (:*

Comment: I had to use the AfterViewChecked instead of the AfterViewInit as well.

Comment: I was using `AfterViewInit` but I forgot to inject `ChangeDetectorRef`. This answer saved me today. thanks :-)

Comment: This resolution fixed my problem with a mat-checkbox. Thanks mate!

Comment: I put ChangeDetectorRef() one line after the variable that changes and works, thanks!

Comment: The framework itself could have known that the change happened in a lifecycle method (ngAfterViewInit) and could have called the additional change detection by itself. Leaving it to the user of the framework to tie up the loose ends is poor design. Scratching head emoji.

Answer (score 95):

`ngAfterViewChecked()` worked for me:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core'; //import ChangeDetectorRef

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
ngAfterViewChecked(){
   //your code to update the model
   this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: As drew mentioned, the angular's change detection cycle which is of two phase, has to detect changes after the child's view is modified, and I feel the best way to do that is using the lifecycle hook provided by angular itself, and asking angular to manually detect the change and bind it. My personal opinion is this seems an appropriate answer.

Comment: This work for me, for loading hierarchy dynamic component inside together.

Comment: The only problem is it will run every time whenever you perform any action on screen

Answer (score 68):

I fixed this by adding ChangeDetectionStrategy from angular core.

```
import {  Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'page1',
  templateUrl: 'page1.html',
})
```

Comment: This worked for me. I wonder what's the difference between this and using ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: Hmm... Then the change detector's mode will be initially set to `CheckOnce` ([documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy))

Comment: Yes, the error/warning is gone. But it is taking way much loading time than before like 5-7 seconds difference which is huge.

Comment: @KapilRaghuwanshi Run `this.cdr.detectChanges();` after whatever you are trying to load. Because it might be because change detection is not triggering

Comment: dont use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,`
this will prevent lifecycle between html and ts

Comment: @KapilRaghuwanshi Did you solve your problem of long loading time?

Comment: @BanAnanas it's too old comment bro, tbh I forgot which project I have used this for

Answer (score 54):

Can't you use `ngOnInit` because you just changing the member variable `message`?

If you want to access a reference to a child component `@ViewChild(ChildComponent)`, you indeed need to wait for it with `ngAfterViewInit`.

A dirty fix is to call the `updateMessage()` in the next event loop with e.g. setTimeout.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.updateMessage();
  }, 1);
}
```

Comment: Changing my code into the ngOnInit method worked for me.

Answer (score 49):

For this I have tried above answers many does not work in latest version of Angular (6 or later)

I am using Material control that required changes after first binding done.

```
    export class AbcClass implements OnInit, AfterContentChecked{
        constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
        ngOnInit(){
            // your tasks
        }
        ngAfterContentChecked() {
            this.ref.detectChanges();
        }
    }
```

Adding my answer so, this helps some solve specific issue.

Comment: This actually worked for my case, but you have a typo, after implementing AfterContentChecked you should be calling ngAfterContentChecked, not ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: I am currently on version 8.2.0 :)

Comment: I recommend this answer if none of above does not work.

Comment: afterContentChecked is called every time the DOM is recalculated or rechecked. Intimating from Angular version 9

Comment: Yes https://angular.io/api/core/AfterContentChecked you are right its default method after the change event

Answer (score 44):

I switched from AfterViewInit to AfterContentChecked and It worked for me.

**Here is the process**

1. Add dependency in your constructor:

   `constructor (private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}`
2. and call your login in implemented method code here:

   ```
    ngAfterContentChecked() {
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
     // call or add here your code
    }
   ```

Comment: Yup this worked for me too. I was using AfterViewInit.

Comment: This works and I guess this should be the correct answer.

Comment: To me using `ngAfterContentChecked` doesn't seem to be the smart thing to do regarding performance. In my lttle sample the code will be executed multiple times, even in you scroll after angular finished the view init.Any thoughts on performance?

Answer (score 27):

The article [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) explains the behavior in great details.

The problem with you setup is that `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook is executed after change detection processed DOM updates. And you're effectively changing the property that is used in the template in this hook which means that DOM needs to be re-rendered:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.message = 'all done loading :)'; // needs to be rendered the DOM
  }
```

and this will require another change detection cycle and Angular by design only runs one digest cycle.

You basically have two alternatives how to fix it:

- update the property asynchronously either using `setTimeout`, `Promise.then` or asynchronous observable referenced in the template
- perform the property update in a hook before the DOM update - ngOnInit, ngDoCheck, ngAfterContentInit, ngAfterContentChecked.

Comment: Read your articles:
https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-gentle-introduction-into-change-detection-in-angular-33f9ffff6f10, Will read another one https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f soon. Still could not figure out solution for this problem. can you tell me what happens if I add ngDoCheck or ngAfterContentChecked lifecycle hook and add this this.cdr.markForCheck(); (cdr for ChangeDetectorRef) inside it. Isn't it a right way to check for changes after life cycle hook and subsequent check completes.

Comment: Read your article and Promise.then solved my issue. BTW, it was happening when I comment out `enableProdMode();` , I mean in debug time. NG6, in prod it was not happening but creating a microtask make sense..

Answer (score 19):

This error is coming because existing value is getting updated immediately after getting initialized. So if you will update new value after existing value is rendered in DOM, Then it will work fine.Like mentioned in this article [Angular Debugging "Expression has changed after it was checked"](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/)

for example you can use

```
ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      //code for your new value.
    });
```

}

or

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.paginator.page
      .pipe(
          startWith(null),
          delay(0),
          tap(() => this.dataSource.loadLessons(...))
      ).subscribe();
}
```

As you can see i have not mentioned time in setTimeout method. As it is browser provided API, not a JavaScript API, So this will run seperately in browser stack and will wait till call stack items are finished.

How browser API envokes concept is explained by Philip Roberts in one of Youtube video(What the hack is event loop?).

Comment: Checkout this best content for JS CONCEPTS -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pN6jk0uUrD8&list=PLlasXeu85E9cQ32gLCvAvr9vNaUccPVNP

Answer (score 13):

You just have to update your message in the right lifecycle hook, in this case is `ngAfterContentChecked` instead of `ngAfterViewInit`, because in ngAfterViewInit a check for the variable message has been started but is not yet ended.

see: 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#afterview

so the code will be just:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div>I'm {{message}} </div>`,
})
export class App {
  message: string = 'loading :(';

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
     this.message = 'all done loading :)'
  }      
}
```

see the [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/koGmx7yhg4muh13fUwBE?p=preview) on Plunker.

Comment: I was using a combination of a [`@ViewChildren()` length-based counter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37243960/114900) which was populated by an Observable. This was the only solution that worked for me!

Comment: Combination of `ngAfterContentChecked` and `ChangeDetectorRef` from above worked for me. On `ngAfterContentChecked` called - `this.cdr.detectChanges();`

Answer (score 6):

**Simple:** first detach/remove the change detection in the construction of your component and then enable `detectChanges()` in `ngAfterViewInit()` method

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  this.cdr.detach() // detach/remove the change detection here in constructor
}


ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  // do load objects or other logics here
  
  // at the end of this method, call detectChanges() method.
  this.cdr.detectChanges(); // enable detectChanges here and you're done.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also put your call to updateMessage() in the ngOnInt()-Method, at least it works for me

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.updateMessage();
}
```

In RC1 this does not trigger the exception

Answer (score 4):

You can also create a timer using the rxjs `Observable.timer` function, and then update the message in your subscription:

```
Observable.timer(1).subscribe(()=> this.updateMessage());
```

Answer (score 3):

It throw an error because your code get updated when **ngAfterViewInit()** is called. Mean your initial value got changed when ngAfterViewInit take place, If you call that in **ngAfterContentInit()** then it will not throw an error.

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.updateMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have almost same case, I have an array of products. I have to let users to remove product as per their choices. in the end if there is no product in array then I need to show Cancel button instead of the Back button without reloading page.

I got it done by checking for empty array in  ngAfterViewChecked() life cycle hook.
This is how I got done, Hope it helps :)

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

products: Product[];
someCondition: boolean;

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewChecked() {
  if(!this.someCondition) {
    this.emptyArray();
  }
}

emptyArray() {
    this.someCondition = this.products.length === 0 ? true : false;

    // run change detection explicitly
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}

removeProduct(productId: number) {
    // your logic for removing product.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to put `this.updateMessage();` under `ngOnInit`, like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void { 
  this.updateMessage();
}
```

Comment: Yeah in my case ngAfterViewInit() was causing it so just stuck in ngOnInit

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it happened with a p-radioButton. The problem was that I was using the name attribute (which wasn't needed) alongside the formControlName attribute like this:

```
<p-radioButton formControlName="isApplicant" name="isapplicant" value="T" label="Yes"></p-radioButton>
<p-radioButton formControlName="isApplicant" name="isapplicant" value="T" label="No"></p-radioButton>
```

I also had the initial value "T" bound to the isApplicant form control like this:

```
isApplicant: ["T"]
```

I **fixed** the problem by removing the name attributes in the radio buttons.
Also, because the 2 radio buttons have the same value (T) which is wrong in my case, simply changing one of then to another value (say F) also fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, and I could solve it by using `AfterViewInit` and `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Here is a detailed article.
https://medium.com/@bencabanes/angular-change-detection-strategy-an-introduction-819aaa7204e7

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt comment on @Biranchi s post since I dont have enough reputation, but it fixed the problem for me.

One thing to note!
If adding **changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush** on the component didn't work, and its a child component (dumb component) try adding it to the parent also.

This fixed the bug, but I wonder what are the side effects of this.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error while working with datatable. What happens is when you use *ngFor inside another *ngFor datatable throw this error as it interepts angular change cycle. SO instead of using datatable inside datatable use one regular table or replace mf.data with the array name. This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think a most simple solution would be as follows:

1. Make one implementation of assigning a value to some variable i.e. via function or setter.
2. Create a class variable `(static working: boolean)` in the class where this function exists and every time you call the function, simply make it true whichever you like. Within the function, if the value of working is true, then simply return right away without doing anything. else, perform the task you want. Make sure to change this variable to false once the task is completed i.e. at the end of the line of codes or within the subscribe method when you are done assigning values!

Answer (score 0):

Good answers. However, it appears to me, that when I am using:
ChangeDetectorRef and AfterViewInit,
Angular gets into a few extra rendering cycles and if my HTML code is not designed with really good care or has a need for several calls to functions in the TS code  that depend on the refresh, I get extra calls for the view rendering, thus extra processing.

Here is a solution I like using, because I do not have to worry about any of that, it is programmatically very simple, and requires nothing much extra from me or the system. I use it with no issues whenever Angular gives me hard time with the infamous error: "Expression has changed after it was checked".

I have this little public/exported function, which simply passes my value through a zero delay Promise. What that does, it forces JavaScript/JS into another background cycle, thus separating the value update into next processing cycle, and - preventing the error. (Note that the JS cycle is not the same as the Angular HTML view rendering cycle and is less processing intensive).

```
export async function delayValue(v: any, timeOutMs: number = 0): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(v);
        }, timeOutMs);
      });
}
```

Now, when I need to prevent the error, I simply do:

```
this.myClassValue = await delayValue(newValue);
```

which is just one line of code. There really is no notable delay since the value of timeOutMs = 0.

Here is a typical scenario:

```
myObservable$.subscribe(newValue  = {
    ...                // WHEN NEW VALUE ARRIVES FROM NOTIFIER(S)
    this.handleSubscribedValues(newValue);
    ...
});
                      // THIS MAY GIVE YOU THE ERROR !
private handleSubscribedValues(newValue) {
    this.myClassValue = newValue;
}
                      // SO, USE THIS INSTEAD TO AVOID THE ERROR
private async handleSubscribedValues(newValue) {
    this.myClassValue = await delayValue(newValue);
}
```

You can also use the delayValue() function with some delay/timeout value if you need to wait a bit for something to happen, e.g. give user a few seconds.

Hopefully, this will be useful to some of you.

Answer (score 0):

just move the code to constructor of the component in which you are changing the shared service subject