# Angular 2 Template Component

Tags: angular, components

Hello I want to create a custom dialog component and I want to insert it content on a declarative way, should look like this:

app.action.dialog.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-action-dialog',
    templateUrl: 'app/template/app.action.dialog.component.html'  
})
export class ActionDialog {

    showing: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.showing = false;
    }

    show() {
        this.showing = true;
    }

    hide() {
        this.showing = false;
    }
}
```

app.action.dialog.component.html:

```
<div id="overlay" class="valign-wrapper" 
    *ngIf="showing" (click)="hide()">
    <div class="container valign">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
                <content select="[content]"></content> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

usage example:

```
<app.action.dialog>
    <div content> example </div>
</app.action.dialog>
```

This ain't working, how can I do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I correctly understand your question (provide some content to another component), I think that you could leverage `ng-content`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'field',
  template: `
    <div>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class FormFieldComponent {
  (...)
}
```

and use the component like that:

```
<field>
  <input [(ngModel)]="company.address.street"/>
</field>
```

Hope it hepls you,
Thierry

Answer (score 1):

I think for `<content>` to work you need to switch from the default `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` to `ViewEncapsulation.Native` (and add web-components polyfills on browsers that don't support it natively) or use `<ng-content>` instead which works in all view encapsulation modes.

Comment: I am accepting Thierry answer because he provided code samples. Anyway thanks for your help bro :D