# Angular 2 component without a view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript, angular

Is it possible to use Angular 2 without using a template or an @View?

I'm looking for a similar way like you did the following in example:

**Angular 1**

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="appcontroller">
<div ng-class="{active: isActive()}">
    .....
</div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('appcontroller', function(){
$scope.isActive = function(){
    return true;
}
});
```

I was guessing it would look something like this, if it was possible:

**Angular 2**

index.html

```
<app>
<div [ngclass]="{active: isActive()}">
    .....
</div>
</app>
```

app.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app'
})
export class AppComponent { 
isActive(){
    return true;
}
}
```

But unfortunately I'm getting the error:

```
... must have either 'template', 'templateUrl', or '@View' set.
```

I don't really like putting html in Javascript, so I hope there some sort of workaround or way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, you should implement the `AppComponent` like this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app'
  template: `
    <div [ngClass]="{active: isActive()}">
      .....
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  isActive(){
    return true;
  }
}
```

or using the `templateUrl` property:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app'
  templateUrl: 'component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { 
  isActive(){
    return true;
  }
}
```

and use the component like this:

```
<app></app>
```

If you put some HTML inside the `app` tag, this means that you want to provide some content to the component that can be included in the component template using `ng-content`. Here is a sample: [Angular 2 Template Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950950/angular-2-template-component/34951011#34951011).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: so there's no other way then to put the html (either in code or the .html-file) in the TypeScript file itself?

Comment: You can use the `templateUrl` attribute to reference an HTML file containing the view content... I updated my answer.

Comment: Well I used your above advice and used the templateUrl and was finally able to get the Angular 2 app running.
Thanks again Thierry!

Comment: One of Angular2's flaws, IMO. It's no longer possible to just have a single HTML page. It *must* be fragmented into small pieces, either in JS code (`template`) or in a separate file (`templateUrl`).