# angular2: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(…)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I know, this question was asked already, but I can't find the solution for my particular case I can't not understand real reason of the error.

I have an angularjs2 app which is running fine. Now I would like to import `marked` library.

What I did:

```
npm install marked
tsd install marked --save
```

and the tsd.json

```
{
  "version": "v4",
  "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
  "ref": "master",
  "path": "typings",
  "bundle": "typings/tsd.d.ts",
  "installed": {
    "marked/marked.d.ts": {
      "commit": "cc3d223a946f661eff871787edeb0fcb8f0db156"
    }
  }
}
```

now trying to import "marked" into my component

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import * as marked from 'marked';

@Component({
  selector: 'blog-component',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/blog/blog.html'
})
export class BlogComponent {
  private md: MarkedStatic;

  constructor() {
    this.md = marked.setOptions({});
  }

  getMarked() {
    return this.md.parse("# HELLO");
  }
}
```

This line: `this.md = marked.setOptions({});` produces the error with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`.. removing this line does not end with an error..  I also thing that `MarkedStatic` was imported correclty then. but then ist not possible to parse markdown, because it should be first initialized whith `setOptions`.

So I assume that importing of `marked` fails, or the `setOptions` method fails.. but I can't figure why...

and here the script part of my index.html:

```
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}}
      });
      System
        .import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

Comment: This is likely due to a template URL that can't be resolved. Check all your template URLs and point them in a browser. Do they all work?

Comment: Template url is ok.. It was used without importing the `marked` library and was displayed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this in your SystemJS configuration instead of including it into a `script` element:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
    map: {
      marked: 'node_modules/marked/marked.min.js'
    },
    packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}}
  });
</script>
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/0oSeaIyMWoq5fAKKlJLA?p=preview.

This question could be useful for you:

- [How to detect async change to ng-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137878/how-to-detect-async-change-to-ng-content/35139439#35139439)

Comment: Thank you. This solves this error. Could you explain the reason, why this should be added via "map" and not via "script" directly? what is the difference?

Comment: In fact, you use SystemJS and the `marked.min.js file` doesn't SystemJS to register its module (something like `System.register('marked', ...`) so you need to configure into SystemJS to adapt this / make the bridge.