# use marked in Angular2

Tags: angular, javascript-marked

I'm trying to make a simple Markdown inline editor with Angular2. I tryed several approaches but none seems to work. I installed marked with npm and it is now visible in the projects node_modules directory. 
I can import it and it is recognized by netbeans. Now when ever I use it nothing works and if I open the firefox debuger then i find 
localhost:3000/marked not found.

I put the markdown converter in a service. Which looks the following:

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';

import * as marked from 'marked';

interface IMarkdownConfig {
  sanitize?: boolean,
  gfm?: boolean,
  breaks?: boolean,
  smartypants?: boolean
}

@Injectable()
export class MarkdownService {
  //private md: MarkedStatic;

  constructor() {
    //this.md = marked.setOptions({});
  }

  setConfig(config: IMarkdownConfig) {
   // this.md = marked.setOptions(config);
  }

  convert(markdown: string): string {
    if(!markdown) {
      return '';
    }
    return markdown;
    //return this.md.parse(markdown);
  }
}
```

used like this everything works fine, except that markdown is not translated. If I uncomment all lines with md it stops working. The component in which I'm using it looks like that:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';

import {MarkdownService}  from '../services/markdown-converter' 


@Component({
  selector: 'my-story',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/story.html',
  bindings: [MarkdownService]
})
export class StoryComponent implements OnInit {
    public html: string;
    private md: MarkdownService;

    constructor(
         private _routeParams: RouteParams, private _converter: MarkdownService) {
         this.html ='';
         this.md = _converter;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    public updateValue(val:string) {
        if(!val) { return ''; }
        this.html = val;
    }
}
```

I'm not displaying all the involved files but If there is a file I should provide just ask in the comments. If it is something I didn't get right about Typescript and or Angular2 injection or whatever, any resource of information explaining those concepts is welcome. I have read a lot on the www but it seems that all documents about Angular2 are quite fast outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my problem.

I mentioned marked in my index.html file twice once to include the script I installed with npm and once I maped the name marked to `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.5/marked.js` if I change this to `node_modules/marked/marked.min.js` it doesn't work anymore and I get strange GET 404 errors for my project files.

Then I had some entrys for marked in my `typings.json` and `tsconfig.json` which where suggested on some sites. I removed those. Finally I left the `"marked": "^0.3.5"` entry in my `package.json` file. This is how my index.html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/"/>
    <title>SSE</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        },
        map: {
          marked: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.5/marked.js'
        }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading... </my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sse",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "marked": "^0.3.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "0.6.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^0.7.12"
  }
}
```

I found a lot of similar questions and tryed all their answers as well as the one given by Thierry Templier here but for some reason none of them where working for me, or I was not capable of reproducing them. I feel like there should be a typescript install of marked some where but where ever I add it it doesn't work.

Answer (score 17):

I would import the marked library this way:

```
import marked from 'marked';
```

and use it as you do:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'markdown', 
  template: `
    <div [innerHTML]="convertedData">
    </div>
  `
})
export class MarkdownComponent {
  @Input('data')
  data:string;

  ngOnChanges() { 
    var md = marked.setOptions({});
    this.convertedData = md.parse(this.data);
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/zUstS3T7IJxjQUVCXiAM?p=preview.

This question could also help you:

- [How to detect async change to ng-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137878/how-to-detect-async-change-to-ng-content/35139439#35139439)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Actually I saw your answer at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36081834/angular2-syntaxerror-unexpected-token
but I couldn't make it work. I think my set up is not good. I still think your answer is right and when  I manage to make it work I will mark it as such.

Comment: So now it "works". This is there is no marked not found error anymore but instead /node_modules/systemjs/dist/[myfiles] not found for all my ts files with js.map endings. I guess this is unrelated, but still it was working before I added the map element in system.config as it is sugested in How to detect async change to ng-content

Comment: I finally managed to solve my problem completely, it had something to do with the way marked was configured in my project. I wrote what I have done as an anwer but I'm not sure I should mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Great! That's strange that you have some 404 errors. Could you provide me  the content of these errors (URLs, ...)? Thanks!

Comment: Took me some time, sorry. So I don't remember all errors I ever got, I got a lot, however the one I can reproduce is this one
`[1] 16.04.23 14:45:24 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/markdown-converter.js.map`  here the `markdown-converter` is my component which is obviously not in node_modules but in my app directory. However now I'm not sure anymore if it is related, when ever I have an error some errors like this one appear. Maybe I have done some bad configuration some where.

Answer (score 1):

This project provides some directives for using Markdown with Angular 2. And it is also using the Marked library.

https://github.com/dimpu/angular2-markdown