# Marked module not found using markdownEditor in Angular 2

Tags: angular, markdown

I am trying to use [markdownEditor](https://github.com/tygern/markdownEditor) in Angular 2. I have downloaded the project and ran it and everything works. However when I copy the components in my own project I get the following error in `conversion/markdownConverter.ts`:

> Cannot find module 'node_modules/marked/marked.min.js'

```
//markdownConverter.ts

import * as marked from 'node_modules/marked/marked.min.js'; //<--not found
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class MarkdownConverter {
    private md:MarkedStatic;

    constructor() {
        this.md = marked;
    }

    convert(markdown: string): string {
        //return markdown;
        //return marked.parse("# h");
        return this.md.parse(markdown);
    }
}
```

When I search manually for the module, the `marked` module seems to be installed... I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35139439/4834129) solution, but I can't make it work.

Comment: Did you already try just `import * as marked from 'marked'`?

Comment: yes, I get the same error

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729100/use-marked-in-angular2 (You probably just need to map it in your SystemJS config if you look at the [Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/zUstS3T7IJxjQUVCXiAM?p=preview) )

Comment: I already tried it, but nothing changed