# How to pass async data to child component via ng-content

Tags: angular, asynchronous, data-binding, components

I'm trying to pass data from my API to a child alert component via `ng-content`. Because the data is asynchronous, it is taking a while to be passed through.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

```js
// User Component

isError = false;
errorMessage:string = '';
public errorMessage: string;
public type = 'accent';

  ngOnInit() {
  
    this.auth.getAllUsers()
    .subscribe(results => {
      if (results.error){     
        this.isError = true;
        this.errorMessage = results.message;
      }
    })
  }
```

```html
// Alert Component
<kt-alert [duration]=1000 [type]='type' *ngIf='this.isError' >{{errorMessage}}</kt-alert>
```

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137878/how-to-detect-async-change-to-ng-content it seems to solve your problem.