# Two-way binding in Angular 2 with NgModel and mutating bound property?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2 beta 5.

Here's my view:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="pendingMessage" (keydown.enter)="sendMessage()"></textarea>
```

And here's my component:

```
@Component({
    //...
})
export class AppComponent {
    private _pendingMessage: string;

    public get pendingMessage() {
        return this._pendingMessage;
    }

    public set pendingMessage(value: string) {
        this._pendingMessage = value;
    }

    constructor() {
        this.pendingMessage = "initial stuff"; //this shows up in the text field initially
    }

    public sendMessage() {
        console.log(this.pendingMessage); //here, pending message is indeed whatever I typed in the text field
        this.pendingMessage = "blah";
        //here I expected the textfield to now contain "blah", but it doesn't
    }
}
```

The whole concept of this two-way binding seems to be working alright. When I type some text in the field and hit enter, I can see that `pendingMessage` is indeed whatever I typed into the field.

However, in the line below where I try to set the `pendingMessage` to `"blah"`, I was also expecting this to update the textfield to contain "blah". Why is this not the case? Isn't that the point of two-way bindings?

I know that Angular 2 can't magically know when values change, but I was hoping it would do a dirty check after evaluating the event. Is there any way to make it do such a thing automatically or somehow pick up the change? I would like to avoid using `apply`.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question :-(

Comment: That's okay - I gave you a counter-upvote to remedy the negative one I gave you earlier (I see you don't have a track record of misunderstanding things).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

Add `ngDefaultControl`

```
<paper-input ngDefaultControl [(ng-model)]="address">
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5360

**

I guess this is a current limitation of the `ngModel` implementation. It binds to the `value` field of the element but for `textarea` it's the `text` AFAIR field it should bind to. It seems the `textarea` fires an event that `ngModel` listens to which makes it work in one direction.

You can work around this by implementing a custom `ValueAccessor`

See also
- [ngModel custom ValuesAccessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995938/ngmodel-custom-valuesaccessor)
- [Angular 2 custom form input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948961/angular-2-custom-form-input)
- [Bind angular 2 model to polymer dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981270/bind-angular-2-model-to-polymer-dropdown/33986250)

Comment: Actually textarea seems to be supported https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/default_value_accessor.ts#L19 and it has a `value` property. All looks fine but still doesn't work.

Comment: I created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FB0dpLfIGEwV3mgs3KNJ?p=preview) and can't reproduce.

Comment: Ok, the Plunker uses beta.0 where it works. I updated to beta.3 and it stopped working. Seems to be a recently introduced bug. Caused by `(keydown.enter)`

Comment: What is your suggestion? Do I wait for it to be fixed?

Comment: It seems to be caused by the minified script versions. dev versions work. AFAIK this is a known issue.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7006 I reported the issue to them. Let's see what they reply. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Not in beta 6 either. But they apparently (because of my issue) flagged it as P1, and still "low effort (hour)". I guess we can see it fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 3):

For binding textarea values you can use the change-function:

## Template

```
<textarea id="some-value" (change)="doTextareaValueChange($event)">{{textareaValue}}</textarea>
```

## Component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private textareaValue = '';
  doTextareaValueChange(ev) {
    try {
      this.textareaValue = ev.target.value;
    } catch(e) {
      console.info('could not set textarea-value');
    }
  }
}
```