# How to implement ngModel on custom elements?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Given a simple `input` element I can do this:

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="name" /> {{ name }}
```

This doesn't work for my custom elements:

```html
<my-selfmade-combobox [(ngModel)]="name" values="getValues()" required></my-selfmade-combobox>
```

How can I implement it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353306/2176962

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you really need `[(ngModel)]` (which supports `ngForm`, unlike `[(myProp)]` approach),
I think this link will answer your question:

- [Angular 2 custom form input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948961/angular-2-custom-form-input/34998780#34998780)

We need to implement two things to achieve that:

- A component that provides the logic of your form component. It doesn't need an input since that will be provided by ngModel itself
- A custom `ControlValueAccessor` that will implement the bridge between this component and `ngModel` / `ngControl`

The previous link gives you a complete sample...

Comment: In my opinion, that link help too https://embed.plnkr.co/nqKUSPWb6w5QXr8a0wEu/?show=preview

Answer (score 114):

`[(ngModel)]="item"` is a shorthand for `[ngModel]="item" (ngModelChange)="item = $event"`

That means that if you want to add a 2-way bind property to your component, for example

```html
<app-my-control [(myProp)]="value"></app-my-control>
```

All you need to do in your component is add

```js
@Input()
myProp: string;

// Output prop name must be Input prop name + 'Change'
// Use in your component to write an updated value back out to the parent
@Output()
myPropChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

The `@Input` will handle the write ins and to write a new value back out to the parent, just call `this.myPropChange.emit("Awesome")` (You can put the emit in a setter for your property if you just want to make sure it is updated every time the value changes.)

You can read a more detailed explanation of how/why it works [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html).

---

If you want to use the name `ngModel` (because there are extra directives that bind to elements with `ngModel`), or this is for a `FormControl` element rather than a component (AKA, for use in an `ngForm`), then you will need to play with the `ControlValueAccessor`. A detailed explanation for making your own `FormControl` and why it works can be read [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html).

Answer (score 12):

I implemented the `ngModel` one time for input in my shared components and from then I can extend it very simple.

Only two lines of code:

1. `providers: [createCustomInputControlValueAccessor(MyInputComponent)]`
2. `extends InputComponent`

#### my-input.component.ts

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { InputComponent, createCustomInputControlValueAccessor } from '../../../shared/components/input.component';
@Component({
   selector: 'my-input',
   templateUrl: './my-input-component.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./my-input-component.scss'],
   providers: [createCustomInputControlValueAccessor(MyInputComponent)]
})
export class MyInputComponent extends InputComponent {
    @Input() model: string;
}
```

#### my-input.component.html

```html
<div class="my-input">
    <input [(ngModel)]="model">
</div>
```

#### input.component.ts

```js
import { Component, forwardRef, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';
export function createCustomInputControlValueAccessor(extendedInputComponent: any) {
    return {
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => extendedInputComponent),
        multi: true
    };
}

@Component({
    template: ''
})
export class InputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
    @ViewChild('input') inputRef: ElementRef;

    // The internal data model
    public innerValue: any = '';

    // Placeholders for the callbacks which are later provided
    // by the Control Value Accessor
    private onChangeCallback: any;

    // implements ControlValueAccessor interface
    writeValue(value: any) {
        if (value !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = value;
        }
    }
    // implements ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.onChangeCallback = fn;
    }

    // implements ControlValueAccessor interface - not used, used for touch input
    registerOnTouched() { }

    // change events from the textarea
    private onChange() {
        const input = <HTMLInputElement>this.inputRef.nativeElement;
        // get value from text area
        const newValue = input.value;

        // update the form
        this.onChangeCallback(newValue);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        const inputElement = <HTMLInputElement>this.inputRef.nativeElement;
        inputElement.onchange = () => this.onChange();
        inputElement.onkeyup = () => this.onChange();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**Step 1:** Add the `providers` property below:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'my-cool-element',
    templateUrl: './MyCool.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./MyCool.component.css'],
    providers: [{   // <================================================ ADD THIS
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyCoolComponent),
        multi: true
    }]
})
```

**Step 2:** Implement `ControlValueAccessor`:

```js
    export class MyCoolComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    
      private _value: string;
      // Whatever name for this (myValue) you choose here, use it in the .html file.
      public get myValue(): string { return this._value }
      public set myValue(v: string) {
        if (v !== this._value) {     
          this._value = v;
          this.onChange(v);
        }
      }
    
      constructor() {}
    
      onChange = (_) => { };
      onTouched = () => { };
    
      writeValue(value: any): void {    
        this.myValue = value;
      }
      registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
      }
      registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
      }
      setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
      }
    
    }
```

**Step 3:** In the html, bind whatever control you want to `myValue`:

```js
    <my-cool-element [(value)]="myValue">
              <!-- ..... -->
     </my-cool-element>
```

Comment: where is the `[(ngModel)]` part being implemented in a custom component?

<cutom-component model="something"> then in custom-component, you accept something and bind it to `[(ngModel)]` no?

Comment: @mcha, step 3 is the html for "MyCoolComponent".  
The goal is to make a custom component compatible with the built in ngModel functionality.
So in this case they can now write;
<my-cool-element [(ngModel)]="value"></my-cool-element>

Comment: in order to use [(ngModel)] and not [(myValue)] replace 'myValue' (getter / setter) with 'model'.
also note that there's no need for a setter really, only a getter.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a custom two-way binding yourself. For angular 10, see the official example [SizerComponent](https://v10.angular.io/guide/two-way-binding#:%7E:text=%3Capp-sizer%20%5B(size)%5D=%22fontSizePx%22%3E%3C/app-sizer%3E), here the `[(size)]` behaves just like the `[(ngModel)]`:

```html
<app-sizer [(size)]="fontSizePx"></app-sizer>
```