# angular2 pass ngModel to a child component

Tags: angular, angular2-components, angular2-ngmodel

I have ParentComponent and a ChildComponent, and I need to pass the ngModel in ParentComponent to ChildComponent.

```
// the below is in ParentComponent template
<child-component [(ngModel)]="valueInParentComponent"></child-component>
```

how can I get the value of ngModel in ChildComponent and manipulate it?

Comment: You can make an @Input() on the child component, and than inject it from the parent <child-component [yourinput]="someVariable"/>

Comment: I've made a detailed answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806779/angular-2-large-scale-application-forms-handling/56375605#56375605

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to implement `ControlValueAccessor` in the child class.
It's what defines your component as "having a value" that can be bound to using the angular way.

Read more about it here: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Everywhere I looked, it seemed that I found a solution that required strong coupling using an onChange event in the parent, the entire time knowing there had to be a way to create a component that didn't need any of that. I upvote you with all of my lion's heart.

Answer (score 2):

For Parent -> Child, use @Input

For Child -> Parent, use @Output

So to use both:

**In the Parent Component**

Typescript:

```
  onValueInParentComponentChanged(value: string) {
    this.valueInParentComponent = value;
  }
```

Html

```
<child-component 
 (onValueInParentComponentChanged)="onValueInParentComponentChanged($event)"
 [valueInParentComponent]="valueInParentComponent">
</child-component>
```

**In the Child Component**

Typescript:

```
export class ChildComponent {  
   @Input() valueInParentComponent: string;
   @Output() onValueInParentComponentChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
} 

onChange(){
  this.onValueInParentComponentChanged.emit(this.valueInParentComponent);
}
```

Html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="valueInParentComponent"   
    (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"/>
```

**Full Example**

https://plnkr.co/edit/mc3Jqo3SDDaTueNBSkJN?p=preview

**Other ways to accomplish this:**

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: what if the ngModel property name changed?  then I will have to change the ChildComponent, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to wrap a form control. I wrote a library that helps you do that! [`s-ng-utils`](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/s-ng-utils) has a superclass to use for your parent component: [`WrappedFormControlSuperclass`](https://simontonsoftware.github.io/s-ng-utils/typedoc/classes/wrappedformcontrolsuperclass.html). You can use it like this:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <!-- anything fancy you want in your parent template -->
    <child-component [formControl]="formControl"></child-component>
  `,
  providers: [provideValueAccessor(ParentComponent)],
})
class ParentComponent extends WrappedFormControlSuperclass<ValueType> {
  // This looks unnecessary, but is required for Angular to provide `Injector`
  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    super(injector);
  }
}
```

This assumes that `<child-component>` has a `ControlValueAccessor`, as @Amit's answer suggests. If you are writing `<child-component>` yourself, there is also a superclass in `s-ng-utils` to help with that: [`FormControlSuperclass`](https://simontonsoftware.github.io/s-ng-utils/typedoc/classes/formcontrolsuperclass.html).