# How do I properly get a reference to the host directive in a ControlValueAccessor?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular-ngmodel

How do I properly connect two directives, or a directive to a component (which is a directive too) in angular2 in the *"angular way of writing code"*?

Since the documentation on angular2 is still quite scarce, any insight or reference is greatly appreciated.

---

This is what every angular2 example shows - binding to a *`string`* via `ngModel`:

```typescript
@Component({
    template: 'Hello <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myVariable">!'
})
class ExampleComponent() {
    myVariable: string = 'World';
}
```

---

Suppose I want to use `ngModel` on a *custom component* which does not represent *`string`s*, but any other value, for example a `number` or a class or interface:

```typescript
interface Customer {
    name: string;
    company: string;
    phoneNumbers: string[];
    addresses: Address[];
}
```

```typescript
@Component({
    selector: 'customer-editor',
    template: `
        <p>Customer editor for {{customer.name}}</p>
        <div><input [(ngModel)]="customer.name"></div>`
})
class CustomerEditor {
    customer: Customer;
}
```

Why do I use `ngModel`, you may ask, when any other attribute would make data binding a lot easier? Well, I am implementing a design shim for angular2, and the components would be used like (or alongside) native `<input>`s:

```typescript
<input name="name" [(ngModel)]="user.name">
<pretty-select name="country" [(ngModel)]="user.country" selectBy="countryCode">
    <option value="us">United States of America</option>
    <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
    ...
</pretty-select>
```

`user.country` would be an *object*, not a *string*:

```typescript
interface Country {
    countryCode: string,
    countryName: string
}

class User {
    name: string;
    country: Country;
    ...
}
```

#### What I have got working so far, but "feels wrong":

[GitHub repository for this example](https://github.com/leonadler/angular2-ngmodel/tree/master/src)

To link up the reference supplied to the `ngModel` directive with my `CustomerEditor` component, currently I am using my own `ControlValueAccessor`: *(simplified)*

```typescript
const CUSTOMER_VALUE_ACCESSOR: Provider = CONST_EXPR(
    new Provider(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomerValueAccessor)
    })
);

@Directive({
    selector: 'customer-editor[ngModel]',
    providers: [CUSTOMER_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
@Injectable()
class CustomerValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
    private host: CustomerEditor;

    constructor(element: ElementRef, viewManager: AppViewManager) {
        let hostComponent: any = viewManager.getComponent(element);
        if (hostComponent instanceof CustomerEditor) {
            this.host = hostComponent;
        }
    }

    writeValue(value: any): void {
        if (this.host) { this.host.setCustomer(value); }
    }
}
```

Now, what disturbs me about that `ControlValueAccessor` is the way I get a reference to my host component:

```typescript
        if (hostComponent instanceof CustomerEditor) {
            this.host = hostComponent;
        }
```

This not only requires 3 dependencies where one should suffice (`ElementRef`, `AppViewManager`, `CustomerEditor`), it also feels very wrong to do type-checking during runtime.

How is the "proper" way to get a reference to the host component in angular2?

---

Other things I have tried, but not have gotten to work:

- [This answer by Thierry Templier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34998780/5460631) notes the component class in the constructor of the ControlValueAccessor for it to be injected by angular:

  ```typescript
  class CustomerValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
      constructor(private host: CustomerEditor) { }
  }
  ```

  Unfortunately, that does not work for me, and gives me an exception:

  > Cannot resolve all parameters for 'CustomerValueAccessor'(undefined). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'CustomerValueAccessor' is decorated with Injectable.
- Using `@Host`:

  ```typescript
  class CustomerValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
      constructor(@Host() private editor: CustomerEditor) { }
  }
  ```

  Throws the same exception as the solution above.
- Using `@Optional`:

  ```typescript
  class CustomerValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
      constructor(@Optional() private editor: CustomerEditor) { }
  }
  ```

  Does not throw an exception, but `CustomerEditor` is not injected and stays `null`.

---

Since angular changed/changes very frequently, [the specific versions I am working with might be relevant, which is `angular2@2.0.0-beta.6`](https://github.com/leonadler/angular2-ngmodel/blob/master/package.json#L42).

Comment: I guess if the `CustomValueAccessor` should be an universal one, then it should avoid accessing the host element. Why do you need this? If it is bound to the component, then the component itself could implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface, then access to the host shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: If you use it this way you might need to add the accessor class to `directives`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%c3%bcnter-z%c3%b6chbauer) pointed me into the right direction.

To bind a value on a component with `ngModel`, **the component itself** needs to implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface and provide a `forwardRef` *to itself* in the `providers:` key of the component configuration:

```typescript
const CUSTOMER_VALUE_ACCESSOR: Provider = CONST_EXPR(
    new Provider(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomerEditor),
        multi: true
    })
);

@Component({
    selector: 'customer-editor',
    template: `template for our customer editor`,
    providers: [CUSTOMER_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
class CustomerEditor implements ControlValueAccessor {
    customer: Customer;
    onChange: Function = () => {};
    onTouched: Function = () => {};

    writeValue(customer: Customer): void {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: Function): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: Function): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }
}
```

Usage from a parent component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'customer-list',
    template: `
        <h2>Customers:</h2>
        <p *ngFor="#c of customers">
            <a (click)="editedCustomer = c">Edit {{c.name}}</a>
        </p>
        <hr>
        <customer-editor *ngIf="editedCustomer" [(ngModel)]="editedCustomer">
        </customer-editor>`,
    directives: [CustomerEditor]
})
export class CustomerList {
    private customers: Customer[];
    private editedCustomer: Customer = 0;

    constructor(testData: TestDataProvider) {
         this.customers = testData.getCustomers();
    }
}
```

---

Every example for `ControlValueAccessor` always show how to use it with a separate class or a directive on a host component, never implemented on the host component class itself.

Comment: Been looking for this to do it at same class as it feels natural, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample, it seems that your `CustomerValueAccessor` directive is attached on the `CustomerComponent` component (the one is the selector `customer-editor`) and not one of type `CustomerEditor`. I think that it's the reason why you can't inject it.

What does `CustomEditor` correspond to?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo in my question, not in the example (which is an entire repository), thank you for noticing. But this should be a comment, not an answer, or am I mistaken?