# Angular2 default filter for uninitialized values

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular

Is there a way to substitute default values for component variable bindings in the HTML tags?
For example, currently I use code like so:
    Some text with data binding ="{{searchResult.title || "n/a"}}" not found.

However I don't like this coz when you have 20 fields adding '|| "n/a"' for each and every one of them becomes a little tedious.

Comment: You could use custom ControlValueAccessor s that do that http://stackoverflow.com/a/35824366/217408

Answer (score 0):

You can set your model to "n/a" by default.

```
public modelObject:modelType = new Model({});

constructor(){
   let self = this;
   Object.keys(this.modelObject).forEach(keyElement => {
     self.modelObject[keyElement] = "n/a";
   });
}
```

This will set a default without having it in your binding.
And will be changed when the data is present/overwritten.