# Angular2(Ionic2): Handling the forms in inner component from the outer

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

Good day. I have a problem with figuring out how to handle form validation with appropriate styling when there are nested forms.
The thing that I want to accomplish is the following:
I have a Page, on this page I'm showing the Tabs components with four tabs in it.
Each tab is the separate @Page. The one page that I'm currently working on has a list of some components (**ItemListCmp**). Each individual components (let's call it **ItemCmp**) has a form. This form should be validated and in the case of invalid state do something with the styling of **ItemCmp**. The **ItemListCmp** also has a form that wraps this bunch of **ItemCmp** components and should also be notified somehow, when the status of the sum of all inner forms (**ItemCmp**) changes.

Could you help me with this, or point some source of information related to this question. 
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this by using @ViewChildren decorator.
To put it simply - in my ItemListCmp I'm creating the form(but without the "form" html tag) dynamically in **AfterViewInit** component lifecycle callback

```
// somewhere at the class ItemListCmp
@ViewChildren(ItemCmp) itemCmps: QueryList<ItemCmp>;


ngAfterViewInit() {
const iCmps = this.itemCmps.toArray();
iCmps.map((c: ItemCmp, key: number) => {
  this.listForm.addControl(key.toString(), c.itemForm);
});
this.listForm.statusChanges
  .debounce(() => Observable.timer(800))
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .subscribe((status: string) => {
  if (status === 'VALID') {
    this.onStatusChanged.emit(1);
  } else {
    this.onStatusChanged.emit(0);
  }
});
}
```

http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders/ helps me a lot

Answer (score 2):

I would create `ngForm` / `ngControl` compatible components for `ItemListCmp` and `ItemCmp`. This way you could leverage their status through the `valid` property and also apply some validation. You would be able to add each component as a control within the containing form at each level.

The following article will give some hints about how to implement this in its section "NgModel-compatible component":

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/17/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-2/

This question could also give you more details:

- [Angular 2 custom form input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948961/angular-2-custom-form-input)