# why [(ngModel)] is not working

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am a new bee to angular 2. I have seen multiple answers on stackoverflow but none of them is working in my case here is the error that it is showing

> Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'md-select'.
>   1. If 'md-select' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.

and here is my code 
**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import 'hammerjs';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    NavigationModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
**my component**
export class ToolbarComponent {
  private item: string = '3';
}
```

**in the template of the component**

```
<md-select [(ngModel)]="item">
  <md-option *ngFor="let v of allvalues()" [attr.selected]="v == avalue() ? true : null">{{v | translate}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

please help me in solving this problem its been 2 days I am stuck at this problem.

Comment: You only provided the imports of your app.module, did you include them inside the imports array in the @NgModule? Is the component part of this module?

Comment: yes 
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    NavigationModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})

Comment: And when and where are you seeing that error?

Comment: Where do you declare ToolbarComponent ? Please give all the relevant info..

Comment: please read this. It may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948961/angular-2-custom-form-input/34998780#34998780

Comment: what do u mean by where do I declare toolbaarcomponent? can you please explain a bit, 
it is in the app/navigation directory. Basically in this component I am injeting a service and using its functions which gives me list of the dropdown options , then as you can see in the template i call those functions and show in dropdown, all I want is to show the default value of the dropdown which should be equal to getPreset() function, i tried selected, ngSelected,[selected] all gives same error that i mentioned above replace ngModel with ngSelected or others.

Comment: Are you using webpack? I have the same problem, but only when I do `webpack -p` rather than just `webpack`

Comment: actually. in my case it says 'ngmodel' with a lowercase 'm', so my problem might be different

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who ends up here I believe the anwser is that you need a name property for your input fields inorder for a two way binding to work.

```html
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="name" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name">
```

Comment: great answer, I was struggling with a similar problem and I didn't noticed this, thanks for helping with this!

Comment: You are most welcome xaberue :)