# Angular 2 Pass values on nested components

Tags: angular, ng2-datepicker

So on a simple two components passing data, this should be easy. But on my case I am using a thirdy-party datepicker plugin, then since I have so many date fields on different forms of my app I decided to create a component of my datepicker so that I won't have to repeat the configurations in each view that I use it. The problem now is I am passing a model to the child component which is also being passed to the datepicker component like this:

parent-component.ts

```
...
template: `<my-custom-datepicker-component [model]="model"></my-custom-datepicker-component>
<span>{{ model }}</span>
`
...
export class ParentComponent{
   model: any;
}
```

and in my-custom-datepicker.ts

```
...
template: '<datetime [(ngModel)]="model"></datetime>'
...
export class MyCustomDatepickerComponent{
   @Input() model: any;
}
```

And here's the datepicker plugin i'm using: https://nkalinov.github.io/ng2-datetime/.

My problem is that the date selected doesn't reflect on the model of the parent component. Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you read the guide explaining the different possibilities? [Component Interaction Guide](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: Yes I already did. I think this scenario is more complex than the examples there since there are 3-levels of nested component here from my parent component to the custom datepicker component to the actual datepicker plugin component.

Comment: Add the component code for the three components, we can look into it. The idea is to use `EventEmitter` to pass values from child to parent. You can also make use of Banana Braces `[(x)]` but will have to implement `xChanges` event for `x` in your custom component. Add `parent.component.ts` , `my-custom-datepicker.component.ts` code and a link to the `datetime` component that you are using.

Comment: There i've added it. Basically I just want to display the selected date from the custom datepicker.

Comment: Btw, what do you mean with `xChanges`?

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: @ShaMoh I had no luck on this, I just decided to copy-paste the configuration of all the places where i've used the datepicker. Really hope there was a way for this.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>my-custom-date-picker.component.ts</kbd>

```
template: '<datetime [(ngModel)]="model" 
      (ngModelChange)="dateChanged($event)"></datetime>'
...
export class MyCustomDatepickerComponent{
   @Input() date: any;
   @Output() dateChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
   // dateChanged will be called when datetime model changes
   // this will also trigger model
   dateChanged(date: any){
      this.dateChange.emit(date);
   }
}
```

<kbd>parent.component.ts</kbd>

```
...
template: `<my-custom-datepicker-component 
            [(date)]="programDate"></my-custom-datepicker-component>
<span>{{ programDate }}</span>
`
...
export class ParentComponent{
   programDate: any;
}
```

---

OR

```
...
template: `<my-custom-datepicker-component 
          (dateChange)="customComponentDateChanged($event)" [date]="programDate">
          </my-custom-datepicker-component>
<span>{{ programDate }}</span>
`
...
export class ParentComponent{
   programDate: any;
   customComponentDateChanged(date: any) {
     this.programDate = date;
   }
}
```

This only explains:

1. [Child to parent communication with EventEmitter.](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)
2. [Two-way binding with Event Emitter](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---)

But you are actually trying to create a **custom form element** when you say a custom date picker. If that is the case then it is a bit more complex as you need to implement validations and ngModel/ngControl/ControlValueAccessor as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948961/angular-2-custom-form-input/34998780#34998780)

That being said, If you want to add some new behaviour to `<datetime>` you can always [`extend`](https://scotch.io/tutorials/component-inheritance-in-angular-2) the [original component](https://github.com/nkalinov/ng2-datetime/blob/master/src/ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime.ts). Extending it will keep its functionalities intact (you will have to provide new template/css as @Component decorator doesnt get inherited) and you can add your own.

**Why are you creating a custom component on top of `<datetime>`?**

Answer (score 0):

Give a try like this

in my-custom-datepicker.ts

@Input() model: any;

you can access the model using this.model in your component

Comment: Yes I did put that, please consider all the basic are there.