# Angular 5 pass ngModel through components

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-ngmodel

I've created a simple component that wraps bootstrap's typeahead controller so it's configured the way I want for the app.  The component has a public variable, `selectedWorker` that's the `ngModel` from the typeahead.

So now, when I use this component elsewhere, I'd want to do something like so:

```
<app-worker-lookup [(ngModel)]="foo"></app-worker-lookup>
```

And then have the `foo` variable of the caller be tied to the public variable of the lookup component that has the selected value.  I'm not sure how to implement that.

Comment: Check [Implement two-way data binding for custom property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52290322/387194) you only need to use `ngModel` as `@Input/@Output` name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have `ngModel` available on a component, you'll need to implement the component as a custom form control. This should be relatively straightforward seeing as your component's form behavior will be the same as typeahead's.

[Here's a nice article on how to do this](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html), or a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948961/angular-2-custom-form-input/34998780#34998780) if you prefer.

One thing to note is that in order to implement two-way binding correctly, you'll need to split up your typeahead component's `[(ngModel)]` attribute into `[ngModel]="selectedWorker" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"` so that you can call `writeValue()` in the `onChange` method.

Answer (score 5):

For can use ngModel in your Component your class must implement ControlValueAccesor and add the Component to the provide token

Component

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'component',
    templateUrl: '../component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../component.scss'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => Component),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
}) 
export class Component implements ControlValueAccessor {

        //
        // Now add ngModel property binding
        @Input() ngModel : NgModel;

        ....

        //
        // ControlValueAccessor implementation
        writeValue(value:any) {
           this.value = value;
        }

        registerOnChange(fn) {
            this.propagateChange = fn;
        }

        registerOnTouched(fn){
        }

        private propagateChange = (_:any) => {};
    }
```

Comment: Hi.. i'm getting this, No provider for DecoratorFactory  , you know why?

Comment: Try to reinstall node_modules, you dont must to have problems. Or  stay to sure that you are write well code.

Comment: If you get "no provider for decoratorfactory" you should replace Component with the name of you Component in the useExisting property of the provider.