# How to initialize the value property of a radio button group in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to display a text-field based on the selected value of a radio button group.

If the user selects "Yes", then I want to display the text-field. If the user selects "No", then I don't want to display this text-field.

Below is my HTML:

```
 <radio-button-wrapper
    [(ngModel)]="damageReported"
    name="rdoDamageReported">

    <radio
        id="preselection_damageReported_01"
        heading="Yes"
        name="validationDamageReported"
        value="Yes">
    </radio>

    <radio                          
        id="preselection_damageReported_02"
        heading="No"
        name="validationDamageReported"
        value="No"
        (click)="clearSecondCompanyFields()">
    </radio>
</radio-button-wrapper>

<div class="form-group" *ngIf="damageReported.value === 'Yes'">
    <label
        for="txtOtherCompanyName"
        class="control-label">
            Please state the name of the other insurance company:
    </label>
    <input
        class="form-control"
        id="txtOtherCompanyName"
        name="txtOtherCompanyName"
        [(ngModel)]="otherCompanyName"
        type="text"/>
</div>
```

In my .TS file, I have this uninitialized variable:

```
public damageReported;
```

The error message I am getting in the console is:

> TypeError: _co.damageReported is undefined

I know this is because I haven't initialized ***damageReported*** in my .TS file.

But if I initialize it like so: `damageReported = ''`;

I get this compile error when I try to use the radio button value at a later stage in the code:

```
this.postData(
    this.damageReported.value
)


postData(
    damageReported: string
)
```

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

Can someone please show me how I can initialize the variable while also being able to use the ***.value*** property? Thanks a lot!

Comment: take a look at this [demo](https://angular-vdq3ix.stackblitz.io)

Comment: `*ngIf="damageReported == 'Yes'"`....

Comment: @mast3rd3mon The error isn't in the *ngIf. The error is when I'm using the radio button value in this code: `this.postData(this.damageReported.value)`. This is what's returned when I try to post when I remove `.value`: damageReported: Object { name: "validationDamageReported", value: "Yes", selectedIndex: 0 }

Comment: @user7554035 remove the `.value` on all references to `damageReported`. going by comments on an answer, you want the value of the radio set instead of the variable, in which case, you probably need to use a `@ViewChild()`

Answer (score 0):

Compiler errors are very handy pieces of information that we should try our best to listen to. In this case the compiler is telling you that the type `string` does **not have** a `value` property.

If you look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#String_instances) for string instances you will see that, indeed, it has no `value` property.

To fix your issue, simply remove the `.value` such that your `*ngIf` directive looks like this: `*ngIf="damageReported=== 'Yes'"`. Make sure that you also remove any usage of `.value` when trying to access `strings` in your code.

EDIT:

I believe that in combination with the above, your issue lies in your use of a third party library for your radio group/controls. The `[(ngModel)]` Directive is an Angular Forms Directive that relies on the decorated control having a few key details. The primary detail being the need to implement [Control Value Accessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor). Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948961/angular-2-custom-form-input/34998780#34998780) and/or [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83) post to see how this looks.

In your case, because you are using a third party library, I would suggest creating a 'wrapper' component that implements the above functionality and using that in your templates instead.

Alternatively, if you are willing to **not** use this third party library, and are instead happy to use Angular Material's [Radio Buttons](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview) then all you need to do is the following:

Add a dependency to Angular Material in your project. If using npm: `npm i @angular/material`

In your `ngModule` import the following: `import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';`

Change your template to use Angular Material components:

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="damageReported">
    <mat-radio-button value="Yes"></mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="No"></mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the error isn't in the ***ngIf**. The error is when I'm using the radio button value in this code: `this.postData(this.damageReported.value)`.

Comment: So instead of initialising the variable as an empty string. I want to know how to assign the .value property of damageReported to ''

Comment: Yes, remove the `.value`, there **is no** property on string called `value`, as my answer said. So instead, it looks like : `this.postData(this.damageReported)`

Comment: When I remove `.value`, now when I post the data, instead of getting the value of the **damageReported** radio button, I get an object which contains a value property: `damageReported: Object { name: "validationDamageReported", value: "Yes", selectedIndex: 0 }`

Comment: Can you please post your `postData()` method in your question? Also, you appear to be using some third party libraries or custom components for your radio group and buttons. Can you please include information about them?

Comment: I've posted the `postData()` method above. The library operates the same as bootstrap