# Two-way binding(with banana in box syntax i.e. [(ngModel)]) in case of parent-child relationship

Tags: angular, primeng

Any idea about how primeNg(third-party library like Material) implements two way binding in their components because whenever I make a reusable component I have to provide values to the child using property binding and receive it in the child using @Input and if I want any data from the child I use @Output and receive it in the parent. But as seen in the primeNg reusable components, they can directly use two-way binding to provide and receive values.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 custom form input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948961/angular-2-custom-form-input)

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37786142/6434407).

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement some of native functionality on your component. Like:

1. Adding dynamic attribute
2. Binding dynamic method (for change, key up, key down etc)
3. Need to update the html as well.
   List is more I just mentioned some of basic steps.

Here you can read more about, your own two way binding.

[your own two way binding](https://michaelmovsesov.com/articles/angular-like-two-way-data-binding-vanilla-js)