# angular2 property has changed error

Tags: angular

I have a directive `app.service.ts` which stores the app state data, and I'm trying to use this directive from other components so I can get and set the state of the app (which is working).

however it gives me this error when I try to bind a property from this directive to the view

`EXCEPTION: Expression 'loading: {{loadState}} in App@0:23' has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true' in [loading: {{loadState}} in App@0:23]`

here I'm trying to show loading text, when `appState.get().loadState == true`

**app.service.ts** - *[source](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/app/app.service.ts)*

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {WebpackState} from 'angular2-hmr';

@Injectable()
export class AppState {
  _state = {}; // you must set the initial value
  constructor(webpackState: WebpackState) {
    this._state = webpackState.select('AppState', () => this._state);
  }

  get(prop?: any) {
    return this._state[prop] || this._state;
  }

  set(prop: string, value: any) {
    return this._state[prop] = value;
  }
}
```

**app.ts**

```
import {AppState} from './app.service';

export class App{

   constructor(public appState: AppState) {
      this.appState.set('loadState', false);
   }
   get loadState() { 
      return this.appState.get().loadState;
   }
}
```

**app.html**

```
<div class="app-inner">
  <p>loading: {{loadState}}</p>
    <header></header>
  <main layout="column" layout-fill>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>
</div>
```

assume `app.ts` has a child component `home.ts` and loaded to the view

**home.ts**

```
 export class HomeCmp {
 page;

 constructor(private wp: WPModels, private appState: AppState) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   var pageId = this.appState.get().config.home_id;
   this.appState.set('loadState', true);    // before http request

   this.wp.fetch(WPEnpoint.Pages, pageId).subscribe(
     res => {
       this.page = res;
       this.appState.set('loadState', false);  // after http request
     },
     err => console.log(err)
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: you can use shared object for this. I think `{{loadState}}` in HTML will always throw error this way. Rather try to bind some shared variable used in service. eg. _state={} is a shared object. set some property to it and then in html you can access it through `{{appState._state.someProperty}}`

Comment: @micronyks same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple, by making a special component to display loading state from the state service `app.service.ts`, here is the code:

**LoaderCmp** displays `loadState` attribute from appState service directly.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {AppState} from "../../app.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'loader',
  template: `
   loading state : {{appState._state.loadState}}
  `
})

export class LoaderCmp{
  constructor(private appState: AppState) {}
}
```

**app.service.ts** holds our app states.

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {WebpackState} from 'angular2-hmr';

@Injectable()
export class AppState {
  _state = {}; // you must set the initial value
  constructor(webpackState: WebpackState) {
    this._state = webpackState.select('AppState', () => this._state);
  }

  get(prop?: any) {
    return this._state[prop] || this._state;
  }

  set(prop: string, value: any) {
    return this._state[prop] = value;
  }
}
```

**app.ts** no configuration needed, just add `LoaderCmp` to app's directives.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [HeaderCmp, LoaderCmp],
  template: `
  <div class="app-inner">
    <loader></loader>
    <header></header>
    <main>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
  </div>
  `
})
export class App  {
    constructor() { }
}
```

update app state from any component, for example: **home.ts**

```
export class HomeCmp {
 page;

 constructor(private wp: WPModels, private appState: AppState) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   var pageId = this.appState.get().config.home_id;
   this.appState.set('loadState', true);    // before http request

   this.wp.fetch(WPEnpoint.Pages, pageId).subscribe(
     res => {
       this.page = res;
       this.appState.set('loadState', false);  // after http request
     },
     err => console.log(err)
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could leverage the ChangeDetectorRef class and its method detectChanges.

For this inject it into your App component and call the method in its ngAfterViewInit.

```
 constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

See this question for more details:

- [Custom angular2 form input component with two way binding and validation inside a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811097/custom-angular2-form-input-component-with-two-way-binding-and-validation-inside/34814189)

That being said I would use an observable property into your state service to notify components when it's read.

```
@Injectable()
export class AppStateService {
  state: string;
  state$: Observable<string>;
  private stateObserver : Observer<string>;

  constructor(){
    this.state$ = new Observable(observer => this.stateObserver = observer).share();
  }

  updateState(newState) {
    this.state = newState;
    this.stateObserver.next(newState);
  }
}
```

And in the component:

```
@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(service: AppStateService) {
    service.state$.subscribe(newState => {
      (...)
    });
  }
}
```

See these links for more details:

- [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/35568924)
- [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/34402436#34402436)

Comment: I tried this but it's giving me exactly the same error

Comment: You mean you tried to call `detectChanges`? In which component lifecycle hook? Otherwise I made a typo in my snippet. It's `ngAfterViewInit` instead...

Comment: It seems that there is no need for `detectChanges`, I liked the idea of using observable for the state service. but I choice the normal one `app.service.ts` because it support multiple properties. I wrote the solution  for both ways.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005 
It's a feature of dev mode working as intended. Calling enableProdMode( ) - see when bootstrapping the app prevents the exception from being thrown.

You need to trigger change detection again. [Triggering Angular2 change detection manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually)

Answer (score 0):

`wp` somehow seems to run code outside of Angulars zone. To force the code back into Angulars zone, use `zone.run()` as shown below for code that updates properties, your view binds to:

```ts
import {NgZone} from 'angular2/core';

export class HomeCmp {
 page;

 constructor(private zone:NgZone, private wp: WPModels, private appState: AppState) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   var pageId = this.appState.get().config.home_id;
   this.appState.set('loadState', true);    // before http request

   this.wp.fetch(WPEnpoint.Pages, pageId).subscribe(
     res => {
       this.zone.run(() => {
         this.page = res;
         this.appState.set('loadState', false);  // after http request
       });
     },
     err => console.log(err)
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution by using observable and share function, here we changed the `app.service.ts` with `app.state.ts` which support only one attribute.

**LoaderCmp** displays `loadState` attribute from appState service directly.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {AppStateService} from "../../app.state";

@Component({
  selector: 'loader',
  template: `
   loading state : {{ active }}
  `
})

export class LoaderCmp{
  active;
  constructor(private service: AppStateService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
       this.service.state$.subscribe(newState => {
       this.active = newState;
    });
  }
}
```

**app.state.ts** holds our load state.

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/share";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {Observer} from "rxjs/Observer";
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";

@Injectable()
export class AppStateService {
  state: boolean = false;
  state$: Observable<boolean>;
  private stateObserver : Observer<boolean>;

  constructor(){
    this.state$ = new Observable(observer => this.stateObserver = observer).share();
  }

  updateState(newState) {
      this.state = newState;
      this.stateObserver.next(newState);
  }
}
```

**app.ts** no configuration needed, just add `LoaderCmp` to app's directives.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [HeaderCmp, LoaderCmp],
  template: `
  <div class="app-inner">
    <loader></loader>
    <header></header>
    <main>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
  </div>
  `
})
export class App  {
    constructor() { }
}
```

update app state from any component, for example: **home.ts**

```
export class HomeCmp {
 page;

 constructor(private wp: WPModels, private service: AppStateService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   this.service.updateState(true);    // before http request

   this.wp.fetch(WPEnpoint.Pages, pageId).subscribe(
     res => {
       this.page = res;
       this.service.updateState(false);  // after http request
     },
     err => console.log(err)
   );
 }
}
```