# How to update an Angular2.RC1 child component when it loads?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-forms

I trying to get a child component (custom input) to update correctly when it is loaded.

I'm basing my approach on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34814189/386619 
and while it works once input is provided, I can't get it to show correctly when it is loaded (with an empty).

The behavior I would like to see is:
Component with empty email address property  and Child Component loads, and the child component displays `<div>` with message saying `Please enter a valid email address.`.   Then I type valid input, and it goes away.  If I delete it (or provide invalid input) it returns (that part works now).

My plunk (derived from [@Thierry Templier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1873365/thierry-templier)'s original [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z4uOUq2q4iXdpo0J6R1o?p=preview)):
https://plnkr.co/edit/tvQhuvnN4iP2sz0wbzso?p=preview

It's probably something easy, but I'm missing it. I'm also new to TS/JS/NG2/HTML, so I hope this is an easy answer for someone.

I'm using Angular2.RC1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple answer would be to add this.inputInvalid = true in ngOnInit() or constructor() of your child components, to set default state as invalid.

Comment: I had attempted this and it didn't work, but I probably had a slew of other things wrong when I attempted it the first time.

Comment: Great, also you could use the framework FormBuilder validation mechanism instead of having your own flags/logic, https://github.com/daviddt/angular2-form-validation-example/blob/master/src/app/app.ts