# Two observable variable dependent on each other

Tags: angular

I need advice on how to make observable variable `currentShop` dependent on variable `shopList`.

`AppComponent` reads `shopList` through `shopProvider`. It works without a problem, but I need to modify the code to set `currentShop` from loaded shops.

**AppComponent:**

```
export class AppComponent {

    currentShop;
    shopList;

    constructor(router: Router,shopProvider:ShopProvider){
        this.shopList = shopProvider.shops;
        this.currentShop = shopProvider.currentShop;

        shopProvider.loadShops();
        shopProvider.setCurrentShop(-1);

        router.navigate(['/System']);
    }
}
```

**ShopProvider:**

```
export class ShopProvider{

    private _http:Http;

    shops:Observable<Array<Shop>>;

    currentShop:Observable<Shop>;

    private obServer:any;

    private _shopDataStore : {
        shops: Array<Shop>
    }

    constructor(http:Http){
        this._http = http;
        this.shops = new Observable(observer => this.obServer = observer).share();
        //this.currentShop = ??
        this._shopDataStore = {shops: []};
    }

    setCurrentShop(shopId:number){
       //Code ??
    }

    loadShops(){
        this._http
            .get('/services/shop/list')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                this._shopDataStore.shops = data;
                this.obServer.next(this._shopDataStore.shops);
            })
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>{{currentShop.name | async}}</div>

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="#shop of shopList | async">
        <a [routerLink]="['/Shop', {shopId: shop.id}]">
            <span>{{shop.name}}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for an architecture more similar to:

**ShopService**

```
class Shop {
  constructor(public shopId: Number, public shopName: string) {}
}

@Injectable()
class ShopService {
  shops: Observable<Array<Shop>> = new Observable<Array<Shop>>();
  shopId: Subject<Number> = new Subject<Number>();
  currentShop: Observable<Shop> = new Observable<Shop>();

  public static getShopById(shops: Array<Shop>, shopId: Number): Shop {
    return shops.filter(shop => shop.shopId === shopId)[0];
  }
  public static compareShops(oldShop: Shop, newShop: Shop): Boolean {
    return oldShop.shopId === newShop.shopId;
  }

  constructor(@Inject(Http) private http: Http) {
    this.shops = this.http
      .get('**url here**')
      .map(res => res.json().shops);

    this.currentShop = this.shops
      .combineLatest(this.shopId, ShopService.getShopById)
      .distinctUntilChanged(ShopService.compareShops);
  }

  setCurrentShop(shopId: Number): void {
    this.shopId.next(shopId);
  }
}
```

Usage in your `Component`:

- save `ShopService.currentShop` to a variable in the `Component` (let's say `this.currentShop`
- use `{{ currentShop | async }}` or `.subscribe()` to the `ShopService.currentShop` observable to be given the shop when it changes

See a working example on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/souldreamer/pen/mVqqKe). I like this approach more because I'm not saving any state, which seems more in line with reactive programming.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed instructions! But isn't work for me. This application does not write errors. shopList still works well, but CurrentShop  does not appear :(. If in component will use js .subscribe(res => {console.log(res)}). Displays {id: 1, name: 'Test'}. What could be the problem that it working in a component and in the template not? Here si full code: http://pastebin.com/TZ0cwFJF

Comment: I would also add that I have to put some logs into code and displays only "setting".

Comment: I encountered this problem, too. If you see in my example, I pass `currentShop | async` to a separate component. `currentShop.name | async` tries to treat `name` as an observable... Not sure how to make something like `(currentShop | async).name`. You can subscribe to the `currentShop` observable in your component and keep the `Shop` instance in another variable and use that...

Comment: I found another one problem I do not understand. After each change routeParametr I try to set a value currentShop below shopId route parameter.
http://pastebin.com/WBqdwjxP

Comment: try setting it in `ngAfterViewInit`. It seems to work on my example (but then again, in my example setting it in `ngOnInit` didn't produce errors, even though it didn't actually show the result in the page - the `async` pipe totally missed the change)

Comment: ngAfterViewInit doing the same. I found that somebody has a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked 
I try setTimeout(function(this._shopProvider.setCurrentShop(...))) without second parameter and it helped my. But it's a strange solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

**ShopProvider**

```
private shopsObserver:Observer<Shop[]>;
private currentShopObserver: Observer<Shop>;
private _shopDataStore : {
    shops: [],
    currentShop: undefined
}

constructor(http:Http){
    this._http = http;
    this.shops = new Observable(observer => this.obServer = observer).share();
    this.currentShop = new Observable(observer => this.shopObserver = observer).share();

}

setCurrentShop(shopId:number){
   var item = this._shopDataStore.shops.find(item=>item.shopId == shopId);
   this._shopDataStore.currentShop = item;
   this.currentShopObserver.next(this._shopDataStore.currentShop);
}

loadShops(){
    this._http
        .get('/services/shop/list')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            this._shopDataStore.shops = data;
            this.shopsObserver.next(this._shopDataStore.shops);                
        })
}
```

**AppComponent**

```
export class AppComponent {

    currentShop;
    shopList;

    constructor(router: Router,shopProvider:ShopProvider){
        shopProvider.shops.subscribe(shops=>this.shopList = shops);
        shopProvider.currentShop.subscribe(currentShop => this.currentShop = currentShop);

        shopProvider.loadShops();
        shopProvider.setCurrentShop(-1);

        router.navigate(['/System']);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>{{currentShop?.name}}</div>

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="#shop of shopList">
        <a [routerLink]="['/Shop', {shopId: shop.id}]">
            <span>{{shop.name}}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No worries, I like the solution he proposed as well.