# How to force a component's re-rendering in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

How to force a component's re-rendering in Angular 2?
For debug purposes working with Redux i'd like to force a component to re-render it's view, is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "re-rendering". Update the bindings?

Comment: Just a quick question why you need to force re-rendering?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Triggering Angular2 change detection manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually)

Answer (score 257, accepted):

Rendering happens after change detection.  To force change detection, so that component property values that have changed get propagated to the DOM (and then the browser will render those changes in the view), here are some options:

- [ApplicationRef.tick()](https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef#tick) - similar to Angular 1's `$rootScope.$digest()` -- i.e., check the full component tree
- [NgZone.run(callback)](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#run) - similar to `$rootScope.$apply(callback)` -- i.e., evaluate the callback function inside the Angular 2 zone. I think, but I'm not sure, that this ends up checking the full component tree after executing the callback function.
- [ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges) - similar to `$scope.$digest()` -- i.e., check only this component and its children

You will need to import and then inject `ApplicationRef`, `NgZone`, or `ChangeDetectorRef` into your component.

For your particular scenario, I would recommend the last option if only a single component has changed.

Comment: Any working code on ChangeDetectorRef for final version of angular2? I am now facing a situation where view is not updated after a http's post request to create a new user and then on success pushing the new object to the existing old userlist (used to iterate in view). Quite strange that `this is the first time I am facing an update not working in ng2`. The change detection strategy is default so i know i have not messed up with the change detection strategy.

Comment: @Gary, you should post a new question and include your component and your service code (ideally, include a minimal plunker demonstrating the issue).  A common problem I've seen is not using the proper `this` context in the POST callback.

Comment: Do you know if I can manually trigger the pipes whenever I perform a change? I've tried to trigger the change detection but the pipe doesn't update... I've also tried with `pure:false` in the pipe. It works but it is way too expensive (inefficient) for my use case.

Comment: @ncohen, I'm not aware of any way to manually trigger a pipe update.  You could use a pure pipe and change the object reference whenever you want to trigger an update.  This is discussed under the "Pure Pipes" section of the [Pipes doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html).  Depending on your use case, you might want to use a component property instead of a pipe.  This technique is briefly discussed at the end of the Pipes doc.

Comment: @N-ate, all of the links are fixed.

Comment: ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() does not work for me. I think, it's because there are no changes. I just want to tigger redrawing / computing. Update pipe values. I want to trigger it every x seconds by setInterval. I thinks re-assigning the variable is currently a easy way to do this. But maybe not the best.

Answer (score 53):

tx, found the workaround I needed:

```
  constructor(private zone:NgZone) {
    // enable to for time travel
    this.appStore.subscribe((state) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            console.log('enabled time travel');
        });
    });
```

running zone.run will force the component to re-render

Comment: what is appStore in this context - which kind of variable and its type ? seems to be observable ... but my observable is inside the component which I want to refresh on a click of a button ... and I do not know how to access a child component method/variable from parent/current location

Answer (score 52):

ChangeDetectorRef approach

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class MyComponent {

    constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    selected(item: any) {
        if (item == 'Department')
            this.isDepartment = true;
        else
            this.isDepartment = false;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 37):

I force reload my component using *ngIf.

All the components inside my container goes back to the full lifecycle hooks  .

In the template :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="_reload">
    components here 
</ng-container>
```

Then in the ts file :

```
public _reload = true;

private reload() {
    setTimeout(() => this._reload = false);
    setTimeout(() => this._reload = true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, @loonis!  I felt like this should work, and I had everything except for the `setTimeout()`.  Now mine is working with a simple and lightweight solution!

Comment: 1 thing to note - the container disappearing and appearing again can can cause size changes and the page could flicker

Comment: This is the best solution for me. This solved my translation issue using my custom translator pipe.

Comment: Thanks, a little bit hacky, but that is the only solution that works for my case (slider of videos)

Comment: Except that if you are using @ViewChild() on this component, to get it, then it will be undefined.

Answer (score 17):

Other answers here provide solutions for triggering change detection cycles that will update component's view (which is not same as full re-render).

Full re-render, which would destroy and reinitialize component (calling all lifecycle hooks and rebuilding view) can be done by using `ng-template`, `ng-container` and `ViewContainerRef` in following way:

```
<div>
  <ng-container #outlet >
  </ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #content>
  <child></child>
</ng-template>
```

Then in component having reference to both `#outlet` and `#content` we can clear outlets' content and insert another instance of child component:

```
@ViewChild("outlet", {read: ViewContainerRef}) outletRef: ViewContainerRef;
@ViewChild("content", {read: TemplateRef}) contentRef: TemplateRef<any>;

private rerender() {
    this.outletRef.clear();
    this.outletRef.createEmbeddedView(this.contentRef);
}
```

Additionally initial content should be inserted on `AfterContentInit` hook:

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.outletRef.createEmbeddedView(this.contentRef);
}
```

Full working solution can be found here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-rerender .

Comment: I guess that in previous versions of angular this hook may be correct (not sure). But with newer one (v13 for me) it does not work and anybody interested in this solution should use `ngAfterViewInit`.
BTW, it interestingly is the only solution that worked for me when input's held the previous values despite form model was correct. This occurred when I was switching between routes differentiated by the `:id` route.
In the end I had to call the `rerender` function every time that navigation ended.

Answer (score 13):

`ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` is usually the most focused way of doing this. `ApplicationRef.tick()` is usually too much of a sledgehammer approach.

To use `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`, you'll need this at the top of your component:

```
import {  ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

... then, usually you alias that when you inject it in your constructor like this:

`constructor( private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef ) { ... }`

Then, in the ***appropriate place***, you call it like this:

```
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

*Where* you call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` can be highly significant. You need to *completely* understand the life cycle and exactly how your application is functioning and rendering its components. There's no substitute here for completely doing your homework and making sure you understand the Angular lifecycle inside out. Then, once you understand that, you can use `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` appropriately (sometimes it's very easy to understand where you should use it, other times it can be very complex).