# Listening for document keyevents in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-forms

We're developing a modal in Angular 5. For convenience, the user should be able to close it with the Escape key or select the default option by pressing return. I created a `@HostListener` in my `ModalComponent`:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) { // Return key
      const index = this.modal.buttons.findIndex(button => button.default);
      if (index >= 0) {
        this.modal.buttons[index].fnc();
      }
    } else if (event.keyCode === 27) { // Escape key
      this.closeModalAlt();
    }
  }
```

However, before the `HostListener` receives any key-event, *one has to click on the modal*. When the modal opens and a key is pressed, nothing happens. This is very unconvenient.

I suppose the reason for this behaviour is the `ModalComponent` only listening for key-events when focused. I need `HostListener` to listen for document-wide key-events ([I already tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107008/detect-click-outside-angular-component) `@HostListener('document:keydown',..)`, it didn't work either). **How can I make `@HostListener` listen to all key-events?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect click outside Angular component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107008/detect-click-outside-angular-component)

Comment: Maybe this helps you moving the focus automatically on the modal. https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_ARIA_role%3Ddialog_to_implement_a_modal_dialog_box

Comment: I tried the described approach with `@HostListener('document:keydown')` (as mentioned) but it didn't work. I'll update the question.

Comment: I have tested the code above and it's working for me (although i am on ng6). I think there is another problem with your code. Can you show how you are trying to close the modal? Maybe angular cannot detect your changes in the same tick? alternatively you could insert a console.log to check weather its called or not.

Comment: I did some deeper testing and it seems to be a timing problem (which was hard to discover). We develop our components with ngrx and, when return is pressed when the modal is open, not only the HostListener gets a key event, also the browser clicks the "open modal" button again. I will try to find a solution for this, but this question is resolved hereby... Is there a way to mark it as such?