# Angular 6 - click outside menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, html, typescript

I'm creating a click event to document that close my aside menu, I created example in jquery but i don't want to do this in jquery and I cannot access to 'menu' variable.

How can I write this in pure angular ?

```
import { Component, HostListener, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "../../node_modules/@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  menu: boolean;
  date = new Date();

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickout(event) {
    if(this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      this.menu = false;
    } else {
      console.log('clicked outside');
    }
  }

  constructor(public router: Router,
              private eRef: ElementRef) {}

  showMenu() {
    this.menu = !this.menu;
  }


}
```

**EDIT**
I edited code from duplicate, but I have different idea

Is there other HostListener to ignore aside and button with id ? Or am I thinking wrong ?

When i click on aside or button menu this clickout event must not working, when i click anywhere else it should set me this.menu to false.

```
<aside id="aside" [hidden]="!menu">
  <button class="menu-btn" (click)="menu = false" routerLink="/">Strona Główna</button>
  <button (click)="menu = false" routerLink="/cv">CV</button>
  <button (click)="menu = false" routerLink="/bio">BIO</button>
  <button (click)="menu = false" routerLink="/portfolio">Portfolio</button>
  <button (click)="menu = false" routerLink="/kontakt">Kontakt</button>
</aside>
<button id="menu-btn" [class.aside]="menu" (click)="showMenu()">Klik</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect click outside Angular component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107008/detect-click-outside-angular-component)

Comment: Can you post the html code?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yup it works, but i see answers in console.log() instead of displaying text, and when i click only on button it shows me clicked outside, anywhere else shows clicked inside, I want to show me 'clicked inside' inside of aside element and only there, anywhere else should display outside, Is there something like @HostListener('aside') ???

Comment: You could handle the `click` event in the `aside` element, and stop the propagation to avoid the click handler at the document level: `<aside [hidden]="!menu" (click)="handleClickAside(); $event.stopPropagation()">` (with `handleClickAside()` defined in component code).

Comment: Add this as an answer, great work thank you!

Comment: Can u post this as an answer ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40107009/1009922), you can detect the document `click` events with `HostListener`. To make sure that mouse clicks don't reach the document when the menu is clicked, you should stop the propagation of the event in the `click` event handler set on the `aside` element:

```
<aside [hidden]="!menu" (click)="handleAsideClick($event)">
```

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) clickout(event) {
  // Click outside of the menu was detected
  ...
}

handleAsideClick(event: Event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); // Stop the propagation to prevent reaching document
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to simply click outside a menu, you can programmatically trigger a click on the document body with:

```
document.body.click();
```