# How to create dropdown list and bind with data coming from server

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am very new to Angular. I have got some work on Angular.

I need to bind Nested dropdown list for `Json` data which is coming from server by calling Rest Api.

Data has one attribute Level, Specifies the level in the hierarchy of the group. Parent
will have  Immediate `Child=1`, `Grandchild=2` and so on. `Child` and `Grandchild` has Group field, which shows inside which parent menu, child menu will be there.

I have tried it to develop but I found all examples of `bootstrap` with static data in `html` file and separate `CSS` file which was complicated to me.

I want to do it dynamically using `TypeScript`. How can I start working on it.

Comment: Firstly, the data format is `XML` and not `JSON`. Can you also add whatever you have tried? Maybe in more details the approach you adopted.

Comment: @vatz88 - Yeah this is xml just pasted from postman. I have tried `html` code which has static nested lists. I will try to edit it and will post `Json` data. You are not gonna like what I have tried :)

Comment: You don't have to worry what you have coded so far. The approach would be - hardcode the data in ts file, in the html make bindings according to the data you have  to render the dropdown. Once that logic is correct, work on getting the data dynamically, and then let angular with the binding do the magic.

Comment: @vatz88 - My static code was in `html` file. I have idea to start it. You can help me out.

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya there are many child of LgLevel 1, how to identify which grandchild of LgLevel  2 belongs to which child ?

Comment: @SatishPai - `LgLevel2` also has `ParentLocationGroup`. So it would inside that child. In the give data `grandchild` you may not able to find `ParentLocationGroup` record that because I have not posted all data here. If you wish to help me. I will all data as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a sample coded which you need as per nested level data from your json data. Now you can for loop the **formatted** json data in the DOM using **model** data.
I hope this will help you out create a multi-level drop-down

```
groupBy(xs, key) {
   return xs.reduce(function (rv, x) {
     (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
   }, {});
 }

var model;

getData() {
 var   sampleData = {
  "ArrayOfLocationGroup": {
    "LocationGroup": [
      ...
      ...//Server response data
      ],
    "_xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  }
 }    

var list = this.sampleData["ArrayOfLocationGroup"]["LocationGroup"];
var formattedList = [];

list.forEach(element => {

  var obj = {  //Make sure your server response data to like this structure
    "Id": element.Id,
    "Name": element.Name,
    "GroupId": element.GroupId.__text,
    "ParentLocationGroup": element.ParentLocationGroup.__text,
    "LgLevel": element.LgLevel.__text,
    "Child" : []
  }
  formattedList.push(obj);
});

var groupDataList = this.groupBy(formattedList, "LgLevel");

var parents = groupDataList[0];
var child = groupDataList[1];
var childOfChild = groupDataList[2];

child.forEach(c => {
  c.Child = childOfChild.filter(x => x.ParentLocationGroup == c.Id);
})

parents.forEach(p => {
  p.Child = child.filter(x => x.ParentLocationGroup == p.Id);
})

this.model = parents;
}
```

Html File

```
    <ul class="nav site-nav">
     <li class=flyout>
      <a href=#>Dropdown</a>
      <!-- Flyout -->
      <ul class="flyout-content nav stacked">
        <li *ngFor="let parent of model" [class.flyout-alt]="parent.Child.length > 0"><a href=#>{{parent.Name}}</a>
          <ul *ngIf="parent.Child.length > 0" class="flyout-content nav stacked">
            <li *ngFor="let c of parent.Child" [class.flyout-alt]="c.Child.length > 0"><a href=#>{{c.Name}}</a>
              <ul *ngIf="c.Child.length > 0" class="flyout-content nav stacked">
                <li *ngFor="let cc of c.Child" [class.flyout-alt]="cc.Child.length > 0"><a href=#>{{cc.Name}}</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

As per your server response data organize the model data.
**Response json format changed** (**__text** to **#text**)

```
 var obj = {
    "Id": element.Id,
    "Name": element.Name && element.Name.#text ? element.Name.#text : element.Name,
    "GroupId": element.GroupId && element.GroupId.#text ? element.GroupId.#text : element.GroupId,
    "ParentLocationGroup": element.ParentLocationGroup && element.ParentLocationGroup.#text ? element.ParentLocationGroup.#text : element.ParentLocationGroup,
    "LgLevel": element.LgLevel && element.LgLevel.#text ? element.LgLevel.#text : element.LgLevel,
    "Child" : []
  }
```

Comment: Can you please post .html file as well.

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya Do you need select tag dropdown or just dropdown ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/csswizardry/Zj4eb/))?

Comment: I need like it is showing in dolor option from the above link.

Comment: I am little confuse with your code. You are not using `getData` anywhere. Could you please check your code one and add opening and closings.

Comment: `getData` is just a method and you can call it where you want to use. In that method I am formatting the **json** data to display in the html. This is just a sample code.

Comment: I added my sample code to **stackblitz**. Try this link [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z454ne)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208481/discussion-between-yaseer-and-arvind-chourasiya).

Answer (score 4):

It seems you already have another answer that meets your requirements. But this solution took me sometime to come up with. So decided to post it anyway.

The below code snippet is used to construct the tree like structure of the parent-child hierarchical data:

```
  processData(data) {
    let locationData = data.ArrayOfLocationGroup.LocationGroup;
    let level0 = [];
    let tempMap = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < locationData.length; i++) {
      let currItem = this.getDataObject(locationData[i]);
      if (tempMap[currItem.id] == undefined) {
        tempMap[currItem.id] = currItem;
        if (tempMap[currItem.parentLocationGroup] == undefined) {
          tempMap[currItem.parentLocationGroup] = { children: [] };
        }
        tempMap[currItem.parentLocationGroup].children.push(currItem);
      } else {
        if (tempMap[currItem.id]) {
          currItem.children = tempMap[currItem.id].children;
        }
        tempMap[currItem.id] = currItem;
        if (tempMap[currItem.parentLocationGroup] == undefined) {
          tempMap[currItem.parentLocationGroup] = { children: [] };
        }
        tempMap[currItem.parentLocationGroup].children.push(currItem);
      }
      if (currItem.lgLevel == "0") {
        if (level0.indexOf(currItem) == -1) {
          level0.push(currItem);
        }
      }
    }
    this.levelData = level0;
  }
```

The aggregated data is passed as input to a `dropdown` component which renders it as a multilevel dropdown menu.

This solution will supposedly work for any level of children. The `dropdown` component can be modified to change the way the data is rendered as per your requirements.

I took the `html` and `css` for the multilevel dropdown menu from here: 
https://phppot.com/css/multilevel-dropdown-menu-with-pure-css/
The code to close the menu dropdown when clicked outside from this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59234391/9262488

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: I have checked your code. It's working. Thank you for posting answer. Can you please tell me how are you getting my data. for http request(mocky.io).

Comment: Mocky is a online tool for creating mock rest api. I took the data you posted and used it to create a rest api using mocky.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a tree component and bind inputs to it recursively?

The proposed solution is

- depth-agnostic - it will work for any number of levels in your data tree (even if it changes ad-hoc)
- quite efficient - it aggregates your data in `O(n)`.

---

First design the data model - it has to be a tree-node structure:

```ts
export interface GroupId { /* appropriate members... */ }

export interface ParentLocationGroup { /* other members... */ __text: string; }

export interface LgLevel { /* other members... */ __text: string; }

export interface DataModel {
  Id: string,
  Name: string,
  GroupId: GroupId,
  ParentLocationGroup: ParentLocationGroup,
  LgLevel: LgLevel,
  children: DataModel[]
}
```

Then aggregate your data in the top-level component (or even better - in your data service; you should be able to abstract that easily enough):

```ts
// dropdown.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown',
  template: `
    <ul class="nav site-nav">
      <li class=flyout>
        <a href=#>Dropdown</a>
        <app-dynamic-flyout [data]="data"></app-dynamic-flyout>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class DropdownComponent {

  data: DataModel[];

  constructor(dataService: YourDataService){

    let data;
    dataService.getYourData()
      .pipe(map(d => d.ArrayOfLocationGroup.LocationGroup)))
      // Make sure every item has the `children` array property initialized
      // since it does not come with your data
      .subscribe(d => data = d.map(i => ({...i, children: []})));

    // Create a lookup map for building the data tree
    let idMap = data.reduce((acc, curr) => ({...acc, [curr.Id]: curr}), {});
    this.data = data.reduce(
      (acc, curr) => curr.LgLevel.__text == 0 || !curr.ParentLocationGroup
        // Either the level is 0 or there is no parent group
        // (the logic is unclear here - even some of your lvl 0 nodes have a `ParentGroup`)
        // -> we assume this is a top-level node and put it to the accumulator
        ? [...acc, curr]
        // Otherwise push this node to an appropriate `children` array
        // and return the current accumulator
        : idMap[curr.ParentLocationGroup.__text].children.push(curr) && acc, 
      []
    );
  }
}
```

And create the recurrent dynamic flyout component:

```ts
// dynamic-flyout.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-flyout',
  template: `
    <ul *ngIf="!!data.length" class="flyout-content nav stacked">
      <li *ngFor="let item of data" [class.flyout-alt]="!!item.children.length">
        <a href=#>{{item.Name}}</a>
        <app-dynamic-flyout [data]="item.children"></app-dynamic-flyout>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class DynamicFlyoutComponent {
  @Input() data: DataModel[];
}
```

The solution is not tested but it shall point you in a right direction...

Hope this helps a little :-)