# Angular custom clickaway listener is triggered if a child component is removed using *ngIf

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular2-directives, angular9, angular-ng-if

I have a clickaway listener as a directive that uses `@HostListener` put on `App.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private clickaway: ClickawayService) {}

  @HostListener("document:click", ["$event"]) documentClick(event: any): void {
    this.clickaway.target.next(event.target);
  }
}
```

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[clickaway]",
})
export class ClickawayDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() clickaway = null;

  private subscription: Subscription = null;
  constructor(
    private clickawayService: ClickawayService,
    private eleRef: ElementRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.clickawayService.target.subscribe((target) => {
      if (!this.eleRef.nativeElement.contains(target)) {
        this.clickaway();
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

The `ClickAway` service just provides a subject to listen to `document:click` on the `AppComponent`.

I am using this directive on a div that has child controlled by *ngIf, something like:

```
<div [clickaway]="doSomething">
  <span *ngIf="isVisible">
    <button (click)="closeSpan()">close</button> //closeSpan() sets isVisible to false.
  </span>
</div>
```

The problem is whenever I click on close, it also triggers the clickaway's doSomething function.

I understand that *ngIf removes the span from dom thus when the directive runs `!this.eleRef.nativeElement.contains(target)` evaluates to false, since element is not there.

What I have tried so far is:

```
closeSpan() {
  setTimeout(() => this.isVisible = false, 100);
}
```

and moving the span out of view using `position: absolute` and very high offsets and removing `*ngIf`.

These solutions work, but I am seeking a more elegant way, preferably the directive itself handling such cases.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In practice, `setTimeout()` tells the browser to invoke the function when it has finished running the event handlers for any currently pending events and has finished updating the current state of the document. [source](https://muffinresearch.co.uk/does-settimeout-solve-the-domcontentloaded-problem/)

Try setting the delay to 0 for a more elegant solution.
Calling `setTimeout` with a delay of 0 (zero) milliseconds doesn't execute the callback function after the given interval.
The execution depends on the number of waiting tasks in the queue. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#:%7E:text=Zero%20delays&text=Calling%20setTimeout%20with%20a%20delay,waiting%20tasks%20in%20the%20queue.)

Your problem is interesting and requires some nip and tuck. I believe you already have the answer. Since you want to do 2 seperate things with the click event, you need to time them according to your preference.

Other possible solutions include using a boolean variable `isHandled: boolean` in your service to avoid an execution. Or something like pushing the current clicked target (not the document clicked target) to your service and do additional checks.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I have tried finding a more elegant solution, but I guess there is none. Though I am leaving this question open for someone having a better understanding of it.

Comment: I am sorry I could not come up with something better. Your problem is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46656671/7322763. You must either use flags or the setTimeout. I would be happy if the timeout works with 0 delay but I would also accept a flag solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with click away, but would something like this work?

```
<div [clickaway]="doSomething()"> 
  <button *ngIf="isVisible" (click)="isVisible=false">close</button>
</div>

doSomething() {
  if(this.isVisible) {
  }
}
```

Comment: I have simplified my problem in the above example, actually I am rendering a chain of components within the div, and this button is analogous to an element inside the component, so I might not be able to get a reference `isVisible` inside doSomething and handling it for each such element seems complex.

Comment: since you are using angular, I can't think of any reason to ever use document:click. why not just use (click)="" ?

Comment: `document:click` is for clickaway directive, it listens to any click on application and calls a `subject.next` with event data the `clickaway` directive subscribes to this subject and when a click event occurs the directive checks if the clicked element is the child of the host element or not, which tells it, if the click was inside or outside.

Comment: This is what I have implemented for clickaway using @ginalx's answer to some other question. If you have some other approach for this I can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the *ngIf:

```
  <span *ngIf="isVisible">
    <button (click)="closeSpan()">close</button> //closeSpan() sets isVisible to false.
  </span>
```

For hidden:

```
  <span [hidden]="!isVisible">
    <button (click)="closeSpan()">close</button> //closeSpan() sets isVisible to false.
  </span>
```