# Angular 2 - Run Component Method from Component's Constructor?

Tags: angular, events, typescript

```
  constructor() {

    document.addEventListener('someEvent', function(event) {
      console.log(event.data);
      this.test(); //throws error - this.test() is undefined
    });
  }
```

If I move it to `ngOnInit`, it works fine:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.test(); //works ok
  }
```

The function is just a method on the component, defined after the constructor:

```
  public test(){
    console.log('TEST');
  }
```

My end goal is to run the `test()` method of my component every time `someEvent` event fires on the global window (the event comes from raw javascript, i.e. `document.dispatchEvent(event, {'detail': evntPayload});`

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: "this" always holds the reference to its surrounding function therefore you are referencing the anonymous function. One way to handle that is before adding the eventlistener add the line "var that = this;". Now you can call that.test(); Or use the arrow operator as stated in the answers.

Comment: Hey Sascha - the `var self = this` is generally a good javascript solution for a number of things, but I was really looking for Gunter's answer here, since it's Angular 2 specific.

Comment: Yes true, I should've seen it by the ngOnInit(). The "lambda" way is the better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrow functions to keep `this` pointing to the current class instance

```
  constructor() {

    document.addEventListener('someEvent', (event) => { // <<< changed
      console.log(event.data);
      this.test(); //throws error - this.test() is undefined
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Following link should solve what you need. Just bind to different event.

[Angular window resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527456/angular2-window-resize-event)