# How to detect click anywhere on the page by Typescript (Angular2)

Tags: angular, typescript

How to detect click anywhere on the page by Typescript? in AngularJS 2

Comment: On what page ? Every pages ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527456/angular2-window-resize-event/35527852#35527852

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can scope a `HostListener` to the document.

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core'    

class MyComponent {

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
    documentClick(event: MouseEvent) {
        // your click logic
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I got error on documentClick. Any idea why?

Comment: documentClick(event: MouseEvent) {
            this.show = false;
            this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Cannot find name 'documentClick'

Comment: That error doesn't make sense to me; are you trying to call that function somewhere else?

Comment: I fixed it! now I need to use this method in another method. What should I pass as a parameter? this.documentClick('click?');