# Simple way to detect click outside of child component

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to expand and contract child `div` component depending on the value of a variable, but I want to be able to click out of that component (in the parent of the sibling) as well as collapsing it.

Here's an [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mouse-click-anywhere) example. I have attempted to use `HostListener` from what I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234758/how-to-detect-click-anywhere-on-the-page-by-typescript-angular2), but it did not help my case.

```
 @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
    documentClick(event: MouseEvent) {
        // your click logic
    }
```

Objectives:

1. When I click on the child (hello) component, I want it to expand if it is not already and contract if it is already expanded
2. When I click on anything else (ie. parent or sibling component), I want the child (hello) component to contract if it is expanded.

I do not want the child (hello) component to expand when clicking in the parent/sibling.

**Update: Using HostListener**

**hello.component.html**

```
<div class="box" (click)="clicked()" [ngClass]="{large: isEnlarged}">Hello.component</div>
```

**hello.component.ts**

```
export class HelloComponent  {
  isEnlarged = false;

  clicked() {
    this.isEnlarged = !this.isEnlarged;
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  documentClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log('clicked');
    this.isEnlarged = false;
  }
}
```

**app.component**

```
export class AppComponent  {

}
```

Comment: you want the the height of `hello` by clicking the parent?

Comment: "I have attempted to use HostListener from what I found in this question, but it did not help my case..." How so? That's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @ritaj perhaps I was using it incorrectly?

Comment: Well, I don't know. That's a listener for every click on the document, inside or outside of the component. You should post what you've tried with it.

Comment: I will do. I will try to figure it out again.

Comment: @ritaj - I have updated both my Q and my stackblitz with HostListener in use. Could you tell me if I am using it wrongly? Also, please see my acceptance criteria in the question.

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your click handler is setting `expanded` to true *before* document click event handler sets it to false, so it's always false.

You could only set it to false if the event target is not your component:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mouse-click-anywhere-8bwg6p?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

```
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  documentClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log('clicked');
    console.log(event);
    if (event.target.id !== 'box') {
      this.isEnlarged = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It wasn't working for me until I realised that I hadn't set any IDs in the HTML side of things! Thanks for the advice :-)