# Angular 4 TypeScript callaback with this. in block

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a theme that I am converting into an Angular 4 admin panel. The theme has a file called app.js containing a class which I am trying to convert into my `layout.component.ts` In app.js there are several blocks of code that try to access functions outside the class but I have converted all functions into methods of my `layout.component.ts`;

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  this.resizePageContent();
});
```

Running this gives a Javascript error. However there is a method on my `layout.component.ts` that should be used in this case.;

```
this.resizePageContent is not a function
```

So I am wondering which is the best way to convert this such that the `layout.component.ts` method is called instead. This is what I have tried but I am not so sure whether this is the best way to do it and why it works.

```
$(window).resize(()=>{
      this.resizePageContent();
    });
```

After replacing it with the above code the errors have disappeared.

This is a preview of app.js It has over 700 lines of code so I will not be able to paste it all here;

**Update:**

```
var App = function() {
    /* Helper variables - set in uiInit() */
    var page, pageContent, header, footer, sidebar, sScroll, sidebarAlt, sScrollAlt;

    /* Initialization UI Code */
    var uiInit = function() {...};

    /* Page Loading functionality */
    var pageLoading = function(){..};

    /* Gets window width cross browser */
    var getWindowWidth = function(){...};

    /* Sidebar Navigation functionality */
    var handleNav = function() {..};

    /* Scrolls the page (static layout) or the sidebar scroll element (fixed header/sidebars layout) to a specific position - Used when a submenu opens */
    var handlePageScroll = function(sElem, sHeightDiff, sSpeed) {...};

    /* Sidebar Functionality */
    var handleSidebar = function(mode, extra) {...};

    /* Resize #page-content to fill empty space if exists */
    var resizePageContent = function() {...};

    /* Interactive blocks functionality */
    var interactiveBlocks = function() {...};

    /* Scroll to top functionality */
    var scrollToTop = function() {...};

    /* Demo chat functionality (in sidebar) */
    var chatUi = function() {...};

    /* Template Options, change features functionality */
    var templateOptions = function() {...};

    /* Datatables basic Bootstrap integration (pagination integration included under the Datatables plugin in plugins.js) */
    var dtIntegration = function() {...};

    /* Print functionality - Hides all sidebars, prints the page and then restores them (To fix an issue with CSS print styles in webkit browsers)  */
    var handlePrint = function() {...};

    return {
        init: function() {
            uiInit(); // Initialize UI Code
            pageLoading(); // Initialize Page Loading
        },
        sidebar: function(mode, extra) {
            handleSidebar(mode, extra); // Handle sidebars - access functionality from everywhere
        },
        datatables: function() {
            dtIntegration(); // Datatables Bootstrap integration
        },
        pagePrint: function() {
            handlePrint(); // Print functionality
        }
    };
}();

/* Initialize app when page loads */
$(function(){ App.init(); });
```

This is my `layout.component.ts`;

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var jQuery: any;
declare var $: any;
declare var window: any;
declare var document: any;
declare  var Cookies: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout.component.css']
})
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  public page;
  public pageContent;
  public header;
  public footer;
  public sidebar;
  public sScroll;
  public sidebarAlt;
  public sScrollAlt;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.init();
  }

  uiInit (): void {...}

  pageLoading (): void {...}

  getWindowWidth (): any {...}

  handleNav (): any {...}

  handlePageScroll (sElem, sHeightDiff, sSpeed): void {...}

  handleSidebar (mode, extra?:any): any {
    if (mode === 'init') {
      // Init sidebars scrolling functionality
      this.handleSidebar('sidebar-scroll');
      this.handleSidebar('sidebar-alt-scroll');

      // Close the other sidebar if we hover over a partial one
      // In smaller screens (the same applies to resized browsers) two visible sidebars
      // could mess up our main content (not enough space), so we hide the other one :-)
      $('.sidebar-partial #sidebar')
          .mouseenter(function(){ this.handleSidebar('close-sidebar-alt'); });
      $('.sidebar-alt-partial #sidebar-alt')
          .mouseenter(function(){ this.handleSidebar('close-sidebar'); });
    } else {
      var windowW = this.getWindowWidth();

      if (mode === 'toggle-sidebar') {
        if ( windowW > 991) { // Toggle main sidebar in large screens (> 991px)
          this.page.toggleClass('sidebar-visible-lg');

          if (this.page.hasClass('sidebar-mini')) {
            this.page.toggleClass('sidebar-visible-lg-mini');
          }

          if (this.page.hasClass('sidebar-visible-lg')) {
            this.handleSidebar('close-sidebar-alt');
          }

          // If 'toggle-other' is set, open the alternative sidebar when we close this one
          if (extra === 'toggle-other') {
            if (!this.page.hasClass('sidebar-visible-lg')) {
              this.handleSidebar('open-sidebar-alt');
            }
          }
        } else { // Toggle main sidebar in small screens (< 992px)
          this.page.toggleClass('sidebar-visible-xs');

          if (this.page.hasClass('sidebar-visible-xs')) {
            this.handleSidebar('close-sidebar-alt');
          }
        }

        // Handle main sidebar scrolling functionality
        this.handleSidebar('sidebar-scroll');
      }
      else if (mode === 'toggle-sidebar-alt') {
        if ( windowW > 991) { // Toggle alternative sidebar in large screens (> 991px)
          this.page.toggleClass('sidebar-alt-visible-lg');

          if (this.page.hasClass('sidebar-alt-visible-lg')) {
            this.handleSidebar('close-sidebar');
          }

          // If 'toggle-other' is set open the main sidebar when we close the alternative
          if (extra === 'toggle-other') {
            if (!this.page.hasClass('sidebar-alt-visible-lg')) {
              this.handleSidebar('open-sidebar');
            }
          }
        } else { // Toggle alternative sidebar in small screens (< 992px)
          this.page.toggleClass('sidebar-alt-visible-xs');

          if (this.page.hasClass('sidebar-alt-visible-xs')) {
            this.handleSidebar('close-sidebar');
          }
        }
      }
      else if (mode === 'open-sidebar') {
        if ( windowW > 991) { // Open main sidebar in large screens (> 991px)
          if (this.page.hasClass('sidebar-mini')) { this.page.removeClass('sidebar-visible-lg-mini'); }
          this.page.addClass('sidebar-visible-lg');
        } else { // Open main sidebar in small screens (< 992px)
          this.page.addClass('sidebar-visible-xs');
        }

        // Close the other sidebar
        this.handleSidebar('close-sidebar-alt');
      }
      else if (mode === 'open-sidebar-alt') {
        if ( windowW > 991) { // Open alternative sidebar in large screens (> 991px)
          this.page.addClass('sidebar-alt-visible-lg');
        } else { // Open alternative sidebar in small screens (< 992px)
          this.page.addClass('sidebar-alt-visible-xs');
        }

        // Close the other sidebar
        this.handleSidebar('close-sidebar');
      }
      else if (mode === 'close-sidebar') {
        if ( windowW > 991) { // Close main sidebar in large screens (> 991px)
          this.page.removeClass('sidebar-visible-lg');
          if (this.page.hasClass('sidebar-mini')) { this.page.addClass('sidebar-visible-lg-mini'); }
        } else { // Close main sidebar in small screens (< 992px)
          this.page.removeClass('sidebar-visible-xs');
        }
      }
      else if (mode === 'close-sidebar-alt') {
        if ( windowW > 991) { // Close alternative sidebar in large screens (> 991px)
          this.page.removeClass('sidebar-alt-visible-lg');
        } else { // Close alternative sidebar in small screens (< 992px)
          this.page.removeClass('sidebar-alt-visible-xs');
        }
      }
      else if (mode === 'sidebar-scroll') { // Handle main sidebar scrolling
        if (this.page.hasClass('sidebar-mini') && this.page.hasClass('sidebar-visible-lg-mini') && (windowW > 991)) { // Destroy main sidebar scrolling when in mini sidebar mode
          if (this.sScroll.length && this.sScroll.parent('.slimScrollDiv').length) {
            this.sScroll
                .slimScroll({destroy: true});
            this.sScroll
                .attr('style', '');
          }
        }
        else if ((this.page.hasClass('header-fixed-top') || this.page.hasClass('header-fixed-bottom'))) {
          var sHeight = $(window).height();

          if (this.sScroll.length && (!this.sScroll.parent('.slimScrollDiv').length)) { // If scrolling does not exist init it..
            this.sScroll
                .slimScroll({
                  height: sHeight,
                  color: '#fff',
                  size: '3px',
                  touchScrollStep: 100
                });

            // Handle main sidebar's scrolling functionality on resize or orientation change
            var sScrollTimeout;

            $(window).on('resize orientationchange', function(){
              clearTimeout(sScrollTimeout);

              sScrollTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                this.handleSidebar('sidebar-scroll');
              }, 150);
            });
          }
          else { // ..else resize scrolling height
            this.sScroll
                .add(this.sScroll.parent())
                .css('height', sHeight);
          }
        }
      }
      else if (mode === 'sidebar-alt-scroll') { // Init alternative sidebar scrolling
        if ((this.page.hasClass('header-fixed-top') || this.page.hasClass('header-fixed-bottom'))) {
          var sHeightAlt = $(window).height();

          if (this.sScrollAlt.length && (!this.sScrollAlt.parent('.slimScrollDiv').length)) { // If scrolling does not exist init it..
            this.sScrollAlt
                .slimScroll({
                  height: sHeightAlt,
                  color: '#fff',
                  size: '3px',
                  touchScrollStep: 100
                });

            // Resize alternative sidebar scrolling height on window resize or orientation change
            var sScrollAltTimeout;

            $(window).on('resize orientationchange', function(){
              clearTimeout(sScrollAltTimeout);

              sScrollAltTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                this.handleSidebar('sidebar-alt-scroll');
              }, 150);
            });
          }
          else { // ..else resize scrolling height
            this.sScrollAlt
                .add(this.sScrollAlt.parent())
                .css('height', sHeightAlt);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  resizePageContent (): void {...}

  interactiveBlocks (): void {...}

  scrollToTop (): any{...}

  chatUi (): any {...}

  templateOptions (): void {...}

  dtIntegration (): any {...}

  handlePrint (): void {...}


  //Methods from original object
  init (): void {
    this.uiInit(); // Initialize UI Code
    this.pageLoading(); // Initialize Page Loading
  }
  //Originally sidebar
  CallhandleSidebar(mode, extra): void {
    this.handleSidebar(mode, extra); // Handle sidebars - access functionality from everywhere
  }

  datatables() :void {
    this.dtIntegration(); // Datatables Bootstrap integration
  }

  pagePrint (): void {
    this.handlePrint(); // Print functionality
  }

}
```

Also could you give me an example of how TypeScript might output something like this;

```
$(window).resize(()=>{
  this.resizePageContent();
});
```

...just to get a good idea of how it works.

Comment: can you share the layout.component.ts original and edited file, then it will be good to answer your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: I have added the component and app.js code. If this ()=>{} solves it. Then that is my answer

Comment: You can check my post, how can you write one liner code as well as what are the ways to listen for window resize event

Comment: Don't want to sound like a douche but why are you using jQuery in Angular?

Comment: This was just a quick conversation without going through all the previous developer's code, which has over 700 lines. But how would I write somethig like this without JQuery; `$('#sidebar-scroll')` or `$('[data-toggle="popover"], .enable-popover').popover({container: 'body', animation: true});` Supposing some external javascript files are attached to the element as well like bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, using the code

```
$(window).resize(()=>{
  this.resizePageContent();
});
```

is the correct way for accessing functions and variables outside of the scope of the callback function.

When using

```
function() {
  this.something;
}
```

the 'this' is bound to the scope of the function, rather than of the class.

When using

```
() => {
    this.something
}
```

that is using ecmascript 6 arrow notation. Ecmascript 6 sees the introduction of the lexical this, where in the latter case the 'this' keyword refers to the class defined.

For more information see http://es6-features.org/#Lexicalthis and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this .

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do just delegate or one line coder in the callback, go for this:

```
$(window).resize(()=> this.resizePageContent());
```

Or you can use the following too resize the page content:

[another question on stackoverflow to catch the window resizing event in Angular context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527456/angular-window-resize-event)

and make your resizePageContent() method to listen for that event.

Answer (score 0):

Opinion based question, but personally the best way is to use a class field 
and assign an arrow function definition, and to -not- use jQuery while using angular:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizePageContent);
```

Within your class you should then define the method like this:

```
private resizePageContent: EventListener = (event: UIEvent): void => {

};
```

The big advantage of this, is that you can **remove** the event listener, which is *impossible* if you use an anonymous arrow function.

[**plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/c868ygygYAvS6jcj1qFg?p=preview)

Another option is to use `bind(this)` to retain the `this` context:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizePageContent.bind(this));
```

This way you do not need to assign your callback to a field of the class. But using `bind` creates a copy of the method, which makes it harder (not impossible) to remove the event listener

You can also just immediately listen to it from within your component using `@HostListener`. Removing of the event is done internally by angular on destroy of the component

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
public resizePageContent(event: Event) {}
```

The reason you were getting an error is because you were using the `function` keyword. This changes the `this` context to the anonymous function you are defining as callback

Comment: `window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizePageContent);` will end up on loosing the context too.

Comment: @Hitmands no it will not, if you define the `resizePageContent` like I mention. Using a field property instead of a method. Test before you downvote :)

Comment: tested... what's the value of `this` after passing the `this.resizePageContent` as a callback?

Comment: @Hitmands the class it's been called in. Let me clarify my code with types. As you can see you got a class field named `resizePageContent` which has as type `EventListener`, which is a method. Good thing about working this way, is that you can remove the eventListener if you no longer need it, so no memory leaks. Seems like a big advantage to me ;)

Comment: this is ok `window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizePageContent.bind(this));`

Comment: @Hitmands so is the first one, just look at how i define the `resizePageContent`. I've created a [**plnkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/c868ygygYAvS6jcj1qFg?p=preview) for you where you can see it in action. Resize the inner window, and find `App {name: "Angular! v4.3.3", resizePageContent: ƒ}` in your console :)

Comment: your code will work because it gets transpiled down to es5 in this way and compiled into the constructor: `function App() {
            var _this = this;
            this.resizePageContent = function (event) {
                console.log(_this); //App
            };
            this.name = "Angular! v" + VERSION.full;
            window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizePageContent);
        }`

Comment: as you can see, `_this` belongs to the outer scope... but if you target it into es6 it won't work...

Comment: Again, have you even tested it? There is no reason it won't work in es2016. You are either passing an anonymous arrow function, or you are passing a named one. Where you get this in ES2016 for a minimal example: `class TestThis {
    constructor() {
        this.resizePageContent = (event) => {
            console.log(this);
        };
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizePageContent);
    }
}`

Comment: no! this is defining a function into the constructor. This is ES6 `class TestThis { constructor() { window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizePageContent); } resizePageContent() { console.log(this) } }`

Comment: Maybe we should chat... Anyways, that's what I'm saying, it's a `field`, not a method... and the field has as value an arrow function. You are defining a method, I am defining a field... I don't know how else to explain it to you :D

Comment: @Hitmands Or, explain to me how else you would like to use `removeEventListener` inside ES6 if you are using `.bind(this)` or an anonymous arrow function.

Comment: you can explicitly define your listener fn or use `HotListener` but absolutely don't use a trick of your compiler because you won't be able to shut down your transpiler once you won't longer need it...

Comment: But, I am explicitly defining it, as a field of the class instead of a local value, so I can use it throughout the class. And `HostListener` is angular, not es6. It's not a trick, it's best practice. For instance in angular, if you want to attach an event and use `useCapture`, you have to use `addEventListener` and can't use `HostListener`. Now how are you supposed to unbind this listener in `OnDestroy`? Afaik, the only way is a field property with a reference to the method. Otherwise you are having a serious memory leak