# Check window size Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-components

I need to check the window size, if it is < 1400 px (laptops), what is the best way to do it?

If it is less than 1400 I would like to set a variable to true for example.

Comment: Perhaps this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527456/angular-window-resize-event

Comment: maybe you should check responsive-design, if you want to adapt your html to different sizes. As far as i know it can be done by css

Comment: @JohnnyAW I need to set pageSize of devex grid to 5 if its < 1400px, thats why I need this type of check.

Answer (score 11):

You can get these values like that :

```
constructor() {
  // User screen size
  const screenHeight = window.screen.height;
  const screenWidth = window.screen.width;

  // Actual space available in navigator
  const actualHeight = window.innerHeight;
  const actualWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

But this won't change if the user resize it's window.

You can get these new values by using a `HostListener` :

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  this.newInnerHeight = event.target.innerHeight;
  this.newInnerWidth = event.target.innerWidth;
}
```

onResize will be called when the navigator's window is resized. It may be very often, you may need a `Subject` to handle it.

Comment: remember to add <div (window:resize)="onResize($event)" in your html template

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div (window:resize)="onResize($event)">  your html here  </div>
```

JS:

```
onResize($event){
 this.myVariable = event.target.innerWidth > 1400 ? true : false;
}
```