# How to use EventManager to listen to window.resize events in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, dom-events

I'm borrowing some code from this stackoverflow: [Angular window resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527456/angular-window-resize-event)
The author of the answer says I should be using the [EventManager](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/EventManager) if I want to listen for window events from a service and not break Angular Universal.  That being said, is this answer still true? If so, could someone show me why when I subscribe to the `onResize$` Observable logs nothing when the window is resized?

```
import { EventManager } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ResizeService {

  get onResize$(): Observable<Window> {
    return this.resizeSubject.asObservable().filter(_ => !_);
  }

  private resizeSubject: Subject<Window>;

  constructor(private eventManager: EventManager) {
    this.resizeSubject = new Subject();
    this.eventManager.addGlobalEventListener('window', 'resize', this.onResize.bind(this));
  }

  private onResize(event: UIEvent) {
    this.resizeSubject.next(<Window>event.target);
  }
}
```

my-component.ts

```
export class MenuContainer implements OnInit {

  constructor(private resizeService : ResizeService ) {
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.resizeService.onResize$.subscribe(console.log); // never logs when I resize
  }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you filtering out all non-falsy values? `this.resizeSubject.asObservable().filter(_ => !_)`

Comment: I accually don't know what the orginal author was doing with that filter

Comment: Why would the even be falsy

Comment: I have no idea why, but if an event that is not `null` or `undefined`, etc. is emitted, it will be filtered. Seems like a pointless filter, to me. Guaranteed to stop you receiving events.

Comment: yes remove the `.filter()`