# Angular, how to react to a window resize event

Tags: javascript, angular

In a non angular application we can respond to window resize events with the following:

```
  window.onresize = function(event) {
    console.log('changed');
  };
```

However we can't use this in angular applications since it's a bad practice to directly access the window object. How would we implement the above functionality in the 'angular' way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527456/angular-window-resize-event

Answer (score 9):

For anyone who is interested:

```
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']) onResize(event) {
     console.log(event.target.innerWidth;);
  }
```

Credits to: [Angular window resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527456/angular-window-resize-event)

Comment: But this will call the listener dozens of times. A throttle function is needed.