# Angular 4 directive not having effect on page load

Tags: angular

I've written a directive that hides an element depending on screen size.  When the page loads the element that is supposed to be hidden is being initialised.

This is my directive

**mobile-only.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMobileOnly]'
})
export class MobileOnlyDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this.displayElement(window.innerWidth < 992);
  }

  displayElement(isMobile) {
    if (isMobile) {
      this.el.nativeElement.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      this.el.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

It is implemented like this

```
<div appMobileOnly>
  <app-brochure-mobile></app-brochure-mobile>
</div>
```

The directive behaves as expected in that the component isn't rendered to the screen, however the ngOnInit function in the component is being fired.  Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: This behaviour would be better implemented with CSS media queries-- no need to use a directive here

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I had media queries but for some reason I thought a directive would be a better way to go

Comment: I'd argue if it *can* be done with CSS, it *should* be done with CSS

Comment: the use of angular cdk MediaMatcher can help you in this scenario (plus one it if it does :D): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527456/angular-window-resize-event/48841964#48841964

Comment: Don't use it in your contrsuctor, use it in `ngOnInit()`. Also, to display/hide, consider using `ViewContainerRef`, not CSS style. Finally, as other people said, media queries are the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting your component into the DOM and only hiding it visually, so `ngOnInit` fires. You could work with `ngIf` or other *structural directive* but CSS media queries are the way to go in this scenario. 
BTW your code doesn't account for window resizes.

Comment: There's a bit more to the directive than I posted because the screen resize part seems to be working fine. It's just the initial load that was the problem

Comment: @abyrne85 Oh okay, my bad