# Can i adjust the displayed columns of a mat table depending on screen size?

Tags: angular

I am using mat-table, the displayed columns are defined in the following array:

TypeScript:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['date', 'customer', 'project', 'performanceRecord', 'duration', 'status', 'action'];
```

HTML:

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

For mobile phones, i would like to remove some columns and replace the displayedColumns with displayedColumnsForMobilePhones:

```
displayedColumnForMobilesPhones: string[] = ['date', 'customer', 'project'];
```

So i would like to know whether there is a way to change the displayed columns depending on screen size. Is something like this possible?

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="getScreenSize() > XS ? displayedColumn : displayedColumnForMobilePhones; sticky: true"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: getScreenSize() > XS ? displayedColumn : displayedColumnForMobilePhones;"></tr>
```

Or is there any other way to figure out the screensize and adjust the displayedColumn array accordingly? Anything would work, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [BreakpointObserver](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview) of Angular Material.

Another way is to capture the [window:resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527456/angular-window-resize-event) and change the displayed column.

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {

  if(event.target.innerWidth < 600 && !isColumnsMobile) {

    this.displayedColumns = this.displayedColumnForMobilesPhones;
    this.isColumnsMobile = true;

  } else if(event.target.innerWidth >= 600 && isColumnsMobile) {

    this.displayedColumns = this.initialDisplayedColumns;
    this.isColumnsMobile = false;

  }

}
```

You can try to tweak this example to your needs.

There are more ways to implement this, but the idea is the same so changing `displayedColumns` will reset the columns as you wish.

Comment: Thanks, that worked out, i just had to replace the `event.target.innerWidth` with `event.target.screen.availWidth`. I guess i also have to put a similar code of block into the onInit method, because the resize event does not get triggered on the first load, just whenever you resize it afterwards. Or should i just manually call the onResize method within the onInit method?

Comment: Okay i was able to set the displayedColumns inside the onInit method by using the `window.screen.width` property. Everything works now, thanks.

Comment: @M.Dietz you are awesome!