# Update DOM When Screen Changes Size (And After Page Loads) In Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to render a div based on whether or not the screen is a certain size. I am able to do this when the page initially loads, however I'm not understanding how to do so when the window changes size AFTER the page loads. I would like a div to either be a "mobile" div or "!mobile" div depending on current screen size.

Here is the relevant code for my home.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  mobile: Boolean;
}

ngOnInit() {
    if (window.screen.width <= 615) {
      this.mobile = true;
    } else if (window.screen.width >= 616) {
      this.mobile = false;
    }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    if (event.target.innerWidth <= 767) {
      this.mobile = true;
      this.ngOnInit();
    } else if (event.target.innerWidth >= 768) {
      this.mobile = false;
      this.ngOnInit();
    }
  }
```

and here is my home.component.html file div's:

```
<ngb-carousel (window:resize)="onResize($event) *ngIf="mobile">
     <!-- ...additional content within mobile div -->
</ngb-carousel>


 <div (window:resize)="onResize($event) *ngIf="!mobile" class="homepage-img-card row ml-5">
     <!-- ...additional content within non-mobile div -->
</div>
```

Not sure how to correctly bind what's happening in the HostListener to the html in order to render the desired div based on the current window size. I know the HostListener part is working, since I'm able to console.log the current screen size (not included in my example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular window resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527456/angular-window-resize-event)

Comment: don't do this using javascript, use [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64054133/542251). Read up on [responsive design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why not use Media Query-based CSS rules?**

Some simple media query rules in your stylesheet should work much more simply, and not require browser script engine time or angular `ngOnInit()` cycles. Try this:

```css
/* CSS */

ngb-carousel {
  display: none;
}
.homepage-img-card {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  ngb-carousel {
    display: block;
  }
  .homepage-img-card {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

You can dispense then with all of the typescript. These CSS rules will be enough and will apply immediately and seamlessly whenever the viewport is resized.

Comment: Great, thank you. Yeah, I guess it does make more sense to use CSS only for this.