# Angular Get Height and Width of the component

Tags: angular, angular11

I have a component which is manually resized so I've added a listener:

```
@HostListener('window:resize')
  public detectResize(): void {
    // get height and width of the component
    this.theHeight = // the coponent height
    this.theWidth = // the coponent height
  }

 theHeight = '';
 theWidth = '';
```

How can I get the Height and Width of the component?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is listening to the window object, so you can only get the window innerHeight and innerWidth. There are 2 solutions to get the current window height.

**Get the Window Sizes**
[Angular window resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527456/angular-window-resize-event)
Eventbinding:

```html
<div (window:resize)="onResizeHandler($event)">...</div>
```

```js
public onResizeHandler(event): void {
   event.target.innerWidth;
   event.target.innerHeight;
}
```

Host Listener Decorator: (The much cleaner approach!)

```js
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResizeHandler(event: Event): void {
   event.target.innerWidth;
   event.target.innerHeight;
}
```

**Component Sizes:**
There are some ways to get the component size but this is a really inefficient solution!!!!! Be careful while using this. The underlying NativeElement Api will directly access the DOM!
https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef

*EDIT:

To be clear, reading the element with this solution will be fine.
If you need to manipulate your element be sure to use `Renderer2`
https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2*

```js
// Inject a element reference into your component constuctor
...
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {...}

// implement a listener on window:resize and attach the resize handler to it
public onResizeHandler(): void {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetHeight
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetWidth

}
```

**If you only want to change styling on resize events**
Be sure to use @media Queries in your css/scss.
This will be the best way to do so!

Comment: good solution. with regard to your last solution; direct access in order to just read DOM elements should be fine unless he's manipulating them in which case the correct approach would be using `Renderer2` https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Comment: yes, reading is ok, whilst manipulation should not be done using the native element! i'll add this in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own code to detect the element size changes. Or you can use a library - personally, I recommend this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resize-event

It works like a charm.