# Force component to refresh programmatically

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have a Component whose data can be modified by a message sent in the background. This message is updating the data correctly, but the component view is not updating (unless I click around in the application triggering a refresh).  Is there anyway for me to programmatically trigger an update to the component?

Comment: See this http://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2014/6/2/How-do-I-run-code-when-a-variable-changes-with-AngularJS If you have a service in the background you can bind the service to $scope, see this https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#angular-services. i do not know if your message is a service

Comment: This relates to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105374/how-to-force-a-components-re-rendering-in-angular-2?rq=1