# Display PDF in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to display a PDF file in an Angular2 component. The path of that PDF is dynamic and changes with the selection of the user.

Simply using data binding doesn't work:

```
<embed style="width: 100%; height: 100%" id="pdfDisplay" [src]="mailing.pdf" type="application/pdf"/>
```

The `src` attribute will have the correct value but the PDF is not rendered - at least not in Chrome. As far as I know, this is due to the fact that the browser doesn't update if only the attribute changes.
In a non-angular application I got it to work by removing the embed tag completely and adding a new one.

Question: How to do that in Angular2?

Comment: Maybe try forcing a re-render? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105374/how-to-force-a-components-re-rendering-in-angular-2

Comment: @moof2k: Well, the change is detected but angular simply updates the src attribute. It doesn't remove the whole embed element and adds a new one.

Comment: I've never tried this myself, but googling it around it appears people have had better luck embeding pdfs using iframes.. have you tried that?

Comment: Sure. It just triggers a download for me.

Comment: looks like security issue for me, could you make a stackblitz for it?