# How to re-render a component manually Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a way I can re render a component manually, say when a user clicks a button??

I've seen similar posts but none of these worked for me for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105374/how-to-force-a-components-re-rendering-in-angular-2)

For example,

```
renderComponent() {
   // force component re-render
}
```

Comment: did you try using `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() ` ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you meant to manipulate the view (add, remove or reattach) then here is an example:

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ViewRef,TemplateRef} from '@angular/core';

import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'host-comp',
  template: `
    <h1>I am a host component</h1>

    <ng-container #vc><ng-container>

    <br>

    <button (click)="insertChildView()">Insert Child View</button>
    <button (click)="removeChildView()">Remove Child View</button>
    <button (click)="reloadChildView()">Reload Child View</button>

    <ng-template #tpl>
      <child-comp><child-comp>
    <ng-template>

  `
})
export class HostComponent implements AfterViewInit{

  @ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;

  @ViewChild('tpl', {read: TemplateRef}) tpl: TemplateRef<any>;

  childViewRef: ViewRef;

  constructor(){}

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.childViewRef = this.tpl.createEmbeddedView(null);
  }

  insertChildView(){
    this.vc.insert(this.childViewRef);
  }

  removeChildView(){
    this.vc.detach();
  }

  reloadChildView(){
    this.removeChildView();
    setTimeout(() =>{
      this.insertChildView();
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

[live example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-embedded-view)

Comment: Is the timeout only to be visibly appreciable, or is it 'necessary' for asynchrony?

Answer (score 12):

If i understand you properly you are asking about **ChangeDetectionStrategy** 
Angular has two [options](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy)

```
enum ChangeDetectionStrategy {
  OnPush: 0
  Default: 1
}
```

If you use default it simply will "re-render" you view after each event such a click.

If you are using OnPush, it will re-render if you use observable with | async or you can inject  [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) and "ask" to re-render

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.numberOfTicks++;
      // the following is required, otherwise the view will not be updated
      this.ref.markForCheck();
    }, 1000);
  }
```

But this is true if you are running inside of angular. Sometimes if you are listening to external services and you are running outside of NgZone you need to do [ngZone.run](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)

```
this._ngZone.run(() => { console.log('Do change detection here'); });
```

Comment: it does not work, console.log in onInit does not log anything

Comment: @EugenBogdanovich it works as expected if you have other issues post your question without code I dont know how to help\

Comment: from another comment: ChangeDetectorRef does not really re-render it just updates data binding using the digest cycle

Comment: @EugenBogdanovich I got what you are saying, question was edited, and my answer was for original question. So yes you are right change detection will not re-render or recreate component it will just update view.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `detectChanges()` or `markForCheck()` to tell angular to re-render the component again.

Comment: ChangeDetectorRef does not really re-render it just updates data binding using the digest cycle

Answer (score 9):

I have created a Directive for this re-rendering purpose

```js
/**
 * Example:
 *
 * <ng-container *rerender='changingInput'>
 *    this content will be re-rendered everytime `changingInput` changes
 * </ng-container>
 */

import { Directive,
         Input,
         TemplateRef,
         ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[rerender]'
})
export class RerenderDirective {
  constructor(
    private templateRef:    TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer:  ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  // if detects changes of the input `val`, clear and rerender the view
  @Input() set rerender(val) {
    this.viewContainer.clear();
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
  }
}
```

Check out my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anhkind/3a3c4b2833d87468deff829497e271ec) for the latest update.

Comment: Thank you - I've been looking for something this like 1 year already!
calling ChangeDetectorRef methods does't work

Answer (score 8):

HTML

```
<app-component1 *ngIf="FLAG"></app-component1>
```

TS

```
  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
      this.FLAG = true
  }

  renderComponent() {
      this.FLAG = false;
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      this.FLAG = true;
  }
```

Comment: Hacky but it works

Comment: Perfect ! ✌

Answer (score 3):

You could trick the router into rendering a fresh copy of current component by temporarily overriding route reuse strategy.. found in some other SO answer :)
in ngOnInit:

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the answers in this thread but I had to do modifications to make it work. Let me share my working code.

```
.html-----------------

<button (click)="addChild()">ADD</button>
<button (click)="removeChild()">REMOVE</button>

<ng-container #vc></ng-container>
<ng-template #tpl>
   <child-component id ="child-modal"></child-component>
</ng-template>

.ts---------------------
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef, ViewRef } from '@angular/core';

export class ParentComponent{

@ViewChild('vc', { read: ViewContainerRef }) vc: ViewContainerRef;
@ViewChild('tpl', { read: TemplateRef }) tpl: TemplateRef<any>;

addChild(){
let view = this.tpl.createEmbeddedView(null);
this.vc.insert(view);
}

removeChild(){
 this.vc.clear();
}
```

[This page](https://blog.bitsrc.io/creating-modals-in-angular-cb32b126a88e) was helpful. Make sure to add `let view = this.tpl.createEmbeddedView(null);` in `addchild()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Angular library `ngx-rerender` https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-rerender

```html
<stuff-to-rerender *mcRerender="trigger">Some Content</stuff-to-rerender>
```

```js
class MyComponent {
  public trigger: number = 0;

  public rerender(): void {
    this.trigger++;
  }
}
```

Whenever you call the `rerender` function your component is being completely rerendered

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use window.location.reload()