# Angular Chrome Api Data Binding Not Working

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome-extension, data-binding, observable

I am working on chrome extension. I have a `background.js` to fetch data in specific conditions.

1. When the conditions meet am activating the [pageAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction)
2. By the time user clicks extension icon I am sending a message to
   "`background.js`" and "background.js" replying me with data.

Although i'm updating component property but the change is not reflecting the UI.

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  sendResponse(this.data);
});
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


// @ts-ignore
const CHROME = chrome;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Title';
  response: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    CHROME.runtime.sendMessage({
      message: 'Give me data'
    }, response => {
      this.title = response.title;
      this.response = JSON.stringify(response);
      console.log(response.title);
    });
  }

  clickMe() {
    console.log('Before:' + this.title);
    this.title +=  ' !!';
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
  <div style="text-align:center">
   <h1> Title: {{title}}</h1>
   <h1> Response: {{response}}</h1>
  </div>

<button (click)="clickMe()" >Click Me!</button>
```

As far as I concerned, I am updating app.component's property from another scope because of that Angular can't realize the data changed.

**I have added a button when I click the button Angular detect the "title" field has been changed so it updates the UI.**

How can I update UI from another context?

---

**Update**

Because of the changes has been made in another scope Angular couldn't detect the changes,
so I have to force it:

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    CHROME.runtime.sendMessage({
      message: 'Give me data'
    }, response => {
      //...
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Did you try using the arrow function syntax instead of `this` `that`?

Comment: Yes I tried now but same result, data is in the console but UI didn't updated.

Comment: The problem is solved, I have to force Angular to detectChanges, source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35106069/7885651

Comment: Had same issue and your `changeDetectorRef` fix worked for me, thank you

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure why you're using a `Subject` in the first place when you have everything in the same Component. Try getting rid of that and use the `ngOnInit` instead of the `constructor`.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// @ts-ignore
const CHROME = chrome;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Title';
  response: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    CHROME.runtime.sendMessage({
      message: 'Give me data'
    }, response => {
      this.title = response.title;
      this.response = response;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: SiddAjmera I have updated the question can you help me please :)