# Angular ngStyle inside img tag not updating dynamically

Tags: angular, angular8

With this template

```
  <img  src="{{someDynamicImageSrcVar}}" 
  (load)="onImageLoad($event)"
  [ngStyle]="getImageStyle()"                
  >
```

After the image is changed and loads, onImageLoad() updates some properties.

```
getImageStyle() {
  const style = {
    'width.px': this.naturalWidth,
    'height.px': this.naturalHeight
  };
  console.log(style);
  return style;
}
```

The framework calls getImageStyle() which returns a style like

```
{width: "500px", height: "400px"}
```

However, the DOM is not updated apart from the first time getImageStyle() was called.

The style never changes from the initial values.

What should I do to make the style update?

Comment: do you have `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` on your component?

Comment: I checked and it is there.

Comment: well, that may be the cause that it is not rerendered, try removing it and observe

Comment: I removed that line and it had no effect. I can see the src update in the div, but the style is unchanged. I can see a correct style being printed in the console. I also tried cdr.detectChanges() inside the onImageLoad function.

Comment: Can you try now @Akash Srivastav answer?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `ngStyle` is this

```
[ngStyle]="{'width.px':500, 'height.px': 500}"
```

So change your return object to this structure

```
{ 'width.px' : 500, 'height.px' : 500}
```

Comment: Good suggestion. I tried it but it had no effect. Now the style returned is {width.px: 400, height.px: 300}. But the element is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

ngStyle is work like this

> [ngStyle]="{'color': 'blue', 'font-size': '24px', 'font-weight': 'bold'}"

Answer (score 0):

the code is looks good!
if you really returned `{width: "500px", height: "400px"}`
i think you should return the value with single qutation
like  `{width: '500px', height: '400px'}`

I hope to help more :)

Comment: Another good suggestion. I was already using single quotes, but when the console prints the style, it formats double quotes.

Comment: try this answer  [force-a-components-re-rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105374/how-to-force-a-components-re-rendering-in-angular-2) to re-render the page after changes