# Expression X changed after it's checked

Tags: angular

See https://plnkr.co/edit/7K03F7Orscz0PZdeanNK

```
export class Filter implements PipeTransform {
    public transform(value: any, args: any[] = []): any {
        return value.filter(() => true); 
        // return value;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write a pipe that filters an array. The problem is when I filter the array, the filter function returns a new array and then I get an Expression X changed after it's checked error. I don't get this error only if I mutate the array in place, but this is not what I want to do. Is there anyway of transforming input values using a pipe and not get this error?

Comment: In case you didn't know, this error is only thrown in developer mode. I've had a similiar issue when returning the width of an element that was changed because of a scrollbar and I solved it by returning a style object instead. If you always return the same object and only change the attributes of it, you should be able to solve this error, though I don't know if that is possible here.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of the developer mode thing. In this case I'm trying to filter a list, so returning the original array won't work.

Comment: If you assign the return value of the filtered list to an object and always return that object, it should work.

Comment: but I'm piping this to a ngFor expression, how will the ngFor handle a non-array object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expression \_\_\_ has changed after it was checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked)

Answer (score 1):

Cache the result and return the cached result while the passed array or filter arguments didn't change.