# Angular stopwatch pipe: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value

Tags: angular

I created a simple stopwatch pipe which should show me the seconds diff. after a certain date:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({
  name: 'stopwatch',
  pure: false
})
export class StopwatchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: Date, args?: any): any {
    return moment().diff(value);
  }

}
```

I made the pipe impure to permanently detect changes. I also found this thread but I'm not sure how to integrate the change detection in my pipe:
[How to manage Angular2 "expression has changed after it was checked" exception when a component property depends on current datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787038/how-to-manage-angular2-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-exception-w)

Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null: 672162'. Current value: 'null: 672163'.

Question: How to properly return the time diff without having the above error?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the pipe.