# nested form component throw ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError on ng-untouched

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set to a child component a `parentFromGroup` as `@Input` and I am getting famous error,

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-untouched: true'. Current value: 'ng-untouched: false'.
```

I know this error but here I don't understand why, because I set value from parent to child not inverse.
You can check it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-aefa6y?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

If you click "Add article" button then try to write to added field, angular will trow error.

What is the best way to achieve what I'm trying here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage Angular2 "expression has changed after it was checked" exception when a component property depends on current datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787038/how-to-manage-angular2-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-exception-w)

Comment: it is same error but completly different subject (there are a lot way to get this error)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this error using `detectChanges()` from `ChangeDetectorRef` on input filed `(input)` event as follows.

**HTML**

```
<input placeholder="designation" (input)="onInputChange()" formControlName="designation">
```

**TS**

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

 constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  onInputChange() {
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
```

**[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-zbbptm?file=src/app/articles.component.ts).**

Comment: Thank you, i don’t like this solution this is pretty big form. I need bind parentForm in a proper way to child components, im looking right way.

Comment: I heard ControlContainer is maybe the solution without providing @Input but i never used it before, if someone can help thanks