# Not getting the updated value from services Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have a common service and I am using my service to change a variable value using click function between components. But I an getting and undefined error and also

```
ERROR
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngSwitch: count1'. Current value: 'ngSwitch: undefined'.
```

I have a made the stackblitz  demo (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8to3ra?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html) here. It would be a great help if some body just point me out what I am doing wrong. As I am very new to Angular any help would be greatly appreciated.
My first question here is why I am getting undefined in my parent component from service?My second question it is not updating the count value in my parent component?

Comment: What information have you found when you have tried to research this problem?

Comment: may be this is useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39787056/3326975

Comment: ChangeDetectorRef only show the last updated value. I want to update the count value on each click.

Comment: "It would be a great help if some body just point me out what I am doing wrong" You are expected to put a little effort into researching your problem before you post your problem.

Comment: Who told you I am not putting any effort here?

Comment: May be in code `*ngSwitchCase="getPrev()"` you calling this method as a case but this method `getPrev(count: string)` expect one param in component and you getting `undefined` you count at `this.count = this.CommonService.getPrev(count)`.

Comment: @hrdkisback could you please suggest how to solve this problem? Where do I need to modify my code?

Comment: @PiyaliGhosh Please refer the Eliseo's answer.

Comment: @hrdkisback I already did that.

Comment: @PiyaliGhosh Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5tymd?file=src/app/your-data/your-data.component.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208846/discussion-between-piyali-ghosh-and-hrdkisback).

Answer (score 1):

you has anything wrong in your 'your-data.component.html'. It is not ?

```
<div [ngSwitch]="count"> <!--you wrote [ngSwitch]=count -->
        <app-census (next)="onNext($event)" *ngSwitchCase="'count1'"></app-census>
        <!--you wrote <app-application ... *ngSwitchCase="getPrev()">-->
        <app-application (next)="onNext($event)" *ngSwitchCase="'count2'">
        </app-application>        
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I am getting the value in my service. But it is not updating in your-data.compone.ts