# Facing Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: html, angular, typescript, random, background-color

I am trying to assign a random color to the div background using the below example

[Random Color](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-random-color)

But facing below error:

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has
>   changed after it was checked.

You can **check-in console** of created `stackblitz`.

I have already tried the below answers:

1. [How to manage Angular2 "expression has changed after it was checked" exception when a component property depends on current datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787038/how-to-manage-angular2-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-exception-w)
2. [Expression ___ has changed after it was checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked)

But no luck! Can anyone please look into this and help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution for this is to use a directive.

So I created a directive called appRandomColor

Here's the code for it.

```js
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appRandomColor]'
})
export class RandomColorDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.element.nativeElement.style.color = this.getRandomColor();
  }

  getRandomColor() {
    var color = Math.floor(0x1000000 * Math.random()).toString(16);
    return '#' + ('000000' + color).slice(-6);
  }
}
```

And added it to declarations in AppModule

Then I applied it to the *ngFor loop. And no errors.

```
<ul>
    <li class="hero" *ngFor="let hero of heroes" appRandomColor>
      {{ hero }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image: Screenshot with the result wanted by the user]

I suggest reading more about Angular Change Detection because it will help you understand these errors more. 
Here are some articles that I find very helpful

- https://indepth.dev/a-gentle-introduction-into-change-detection-in-angular/
- https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular/

## Edit

On Component.ts

```js
colorsArray = ['#FF5733', '#DA4323', '#FFB1A0', '#BB523C', '#BB2505', '#DE4922'];
```

On Component.html

```html
 <li class="hero" *ngFor="let hero of heroes" [appRandomColor]="colorsArray">
      {{ hero }}
 </li>
```

To add predefined colors array to directive

```js
@Input('appRandomColor') colors: string[]; 

ngOnInit() {
   this.element.nativeElement.style.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]; 
}
```

Comment: Let me try your answer.

Comment: Is there any way to assign random color from pre-defined array of colors?

Comment: Yes,

You can do this: 

``` js
 @Input('appRandomColor') color: string;

 ngOnInit() {
     // if you want to add random color make if statement here to check if the user has 
     // put color on Input
      this.element.nativeElement.style.color = color;
  }
```

on template.html 
``` html
[appRandomColor]=" 'red' " // or can be the variable
```

Comment: Or you can add the pre-defined array of color to appRandomColor directive function .

Comment: can you pls give me an example to add pre-defined array to directive?

Comment: I have 6 pre-defined colors, I want to assign from those only

Comment: Give me the colors, and I edit the answer to your needs.

Comment: #FF5733, #DA4323, #FFB1A0, #BB523C, #BB2505, #DE4922

Comment: any luck for this?

Comment: getting error: Can't bind to 'appRandomColor' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209869/discussion-between-enea-jahollari-and-pathik-vejani).