# Angular I get error expression has changed after it was checked, when I click a button

Tags: angular

I get the following error, when I click a button which I set to show and hide a form field. and I could not figure it out, how to resolve it

```
   ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'disabled: false'. Current value: 'disabled: true'.
at viewDebugError (core.js:20496)
at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:20484)
```

Comment: It's impossible to know why you have this error unless you add your component and template source code. This error usually occurs when you have async pipes in the template and you have intermittent state or you're emitting multiple values before the template is rendered. There is a detailed blog post here that explains more: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manage Angular2 "expression has changed after it was checked" exception when a component property depends on current datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787038/how-to-manage-angular2-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-exception-w)

Answer (score 0):

Use ChangeDetectorRef from angular/core.
Inside constructor

```
private _changeRef:ChangeDetectorRef
```

And inside ngDoCheck lifecycle call markForCheck

```
ngDoCheck() {
this._changeRef.markForCheck()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it should solve your problem:

import the ChangeDetectorRef in your component Read here for details

(https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewChecked)

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private _changeDetRef: ChangeDetectorRef){}
   ngAfterViewChecked(){

    //console.log('----detect change-----');
    this._changeDetRef.detectChanges();
   }
```