# Angular 13 - Binding @Input() to @ViewChild() element causes ExpressionChangedAfterChecked error

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild

I'm having some trouble figuring out why I'm getting this error. I'm familiar with `@ViewChild()` and Angular's lifecycle hooks so I've tried every "right way" of doing things which all render without a problem on the page but still throw this error.  I came across [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787038/how-to-manage-angular2-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-exception-w/54954374#54954374) which has a few solutions and links to information revolving around the issue however nothing I try makes it go away.

My component looks like this

```
export class BoxSizeVariantComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @Input() Width: string = '0px';
  @Input() Title: string = '--';

  @ViewChild('sizeShell', {static: false}) SizeShell! : ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  Size: number = 0;

  constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    
  }
  
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    const BoxObserver = new ResizeObserver((entry) =>{
      this.zone.run(()=> { this.updateSize();});
    });
    
    BoxObserver.observe(this.SizeShell.nativeElement);
    
  }

  private updateSize(): void {
    this.Size = this.SizeShell.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
  }

}
```

and the template

```
<p>{{Title}}</p>
<section class="mainShell">
    <article #sizeShell class="sizeShell" [ngStyle]="{'width': Width}">
        <p>
            {{Size}}px
        </p>
    </article>
    <p>
        {{Size}}px
    </p>
</section>
```

The component I use this in gets embedded into an `<iframe>` with `Renderer2` and has `encapsulation` set to `ViewEncapsulation.shadowDom` so the styling loads.  I do this same thing in other components using `@ViewChild()` and don't get any errors.  I tried changing the change detection to `onPush` and using `ChangeDetectorRef` to force the check to occur.  I've switched `static` back and forth between `true` and `false`, I've tried using the `AfterContentChecked` hook, I don't know what else to try.  Does anyone have any clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: On which property do you get this error?